# Export Graphics[] without white edges

Tags: graphics, export

I am trying to generate & Export[] Image with the below code, but as shown in the images I get some white border around my rectangle.

How could I export an images that stopes right at the edge of my Rectangle[] edges ?

[image]

```
c0 = {RGBColor[23/85, 29/255, 142/255], RGBColor[244/255, 1, 59/255], 
      RGBColor[1, 0, 32/85], RGBColor[18/85, 72/85, 197/255]}


Export[FileNameJoin[{Directory[], "DropBox", ToString[#] <> ".jpg"}],
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Thick],
 White, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {160, 90}],
 Flatten@({Flatten@(Table[
          RandomChoice[{GrayLevel[.15], c0[[#]]}], {3}] & /@ 
        Range[2, 4, 1]),
     MapThread[
      Function[{Xs, Ys},
       Rectangle[{Xs, Ys}, {Xs + 16, Ys + 9}]],
      {Flatten@Table[Range[0, 32, 16], {3}], 
       Flatten@(Table[#, {3}] & /@ 
          Range[63, 81, 9])}]}\[Transpose]),
 Black, Thick, Line[{{0, 63}, {160, 63}}]}, ImageSize -> 300]] & /@
 Range[100]
```

Comment: With `png` files, you can use `Export` with option `Background->None`; but with `jpg` images this trick does not work.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There's another, undocumented, approach, although I can't take credit for discovering this one. The solution you're probably looking for (in the sense that Brett Champion's solution seems to clip off a little too much at the edges) is the `Method` option for `Graphics`:

```
Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> True}
```

e.g. (graphics example from the documentation for `Circle`):

```
Graphics[
  Table[{Hue[t/20], Circle[{Cos[2 Pi t/20], Sin[2 Pi t/20]}, 1]}, {t, 20}], 
  Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> True}
]
```

Note that this has to be written as `Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> True}`. The form `Method -> "ShrinkWrap" -> True` might be expected to work, but it doesn't.

Comment: +1, I didn't know `"ShrinkWrap"` worked in 2D graphics.

Comment: @Oleksandr, definetly does it, Thank You  :-)

Comment: What is the reason for the `Method` option not being documented for `Graphics` -- meaning that its existence is documented but how to use it is not.

Comment: I don't know; I don't have any special insight into that kind of thing. I'm not a WRI employee; I just seem to be mentioning undocumented functionality a lot lately as I'm willing to talk about it whereas whereas WRI, usually, is not.

Comment: `"ShrinkWrap"` works very well, but can take a bit of time to render. If you combine several shrinkwrapped graphics (e.g. via `Inset` or `Grid` inside a dynamic expression like `Manipulate` then you will start to notice the lag.

Answer (score 9):

If you are already dealing with rasterized graphics, `ImageCrop[image]` tries to remove uniformly colored edges.

In version 8.01 there was a bug that sometimes got it wrong, an equivalent workaround was:

```
imcrop[img_] := ImagePad[img, -BorderDimensions[img, 0]]
```

which also shows the rather useful `BorderDimensions[]` in action.

Answer (score 8):

Set the following `Graphics` options:

```
PlotRangePadding -> None
ImagePadding -> None
```

If setting `ImagePadding -> None` is too aggressive, you can add back in fixed amounts of padding with something like `ImagePadding -> 1` or the more general matrix form.

Comment: Thank You but than now seems to eat the edge of the Rectangle Edges. Is there a neat way to fix, Or do I have to double the EdgeThickness[] to have only the inner part ?

Answer (score 5):

If `jpg` is not essential so that you can use `png` instead, setting the background to `None` in `Export` works:

```
Export["tst" <> ToString[#] <> ".png", 
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Thick], White, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {160, 90}], 
 Flatten@({Flatten@(Table[
          RandomChoice[{GrayLevel[.15], c0[[#]]}], {3}] & /@ 
        Range[2, 4, 1]), 
     MapThread[
      Function[{Xs, Ys}, 
       Rectangle[{Xs, Ys}, {Xs + 16, Ys + 9}]], {Flatten@
        Table[Range[0, 32, 16], {3}], 
       Flatten@(Table[#, {3}] & /@ 
          Range[63, 81, 9])}]}\[Transpose]), Black, Thick, 
 Line[{{0, 63}, {160, 63}}]}, ImageSize -> 300], 
Background -> None] & /@ Range[10]
```

You get:

[image: example png image]

EDIT: To change the white rectangle to transparent, try

```
Export["xtst" <> ToString[#] <> ".png", 
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Thick], Opacity[0], 
 Rectangle[{0, 0}, {160, 90}], Opacity[1], 
 Flatten@({Flatten@(Table[
          RandomChoice[{GrayLevel[.15], c0[[#]]}], {3}] & /@ 
        Range[2, 4, 1]), 
     MapThread[
      Function[{Xs, Ys}, 
       Rectangle[{Xs, Ys}, {Xs + 16, Ys + 9}]], {Flatten@
        Table[Range[0, 32, 16], {3}], 
       Flatten@(Table[#, {3}] & /@ 
          Range[63, 81, 9])}]}\[Transpose]), Black, Thick, 
 Line[{{0, 63}, {160, 63}}]}, ImageSize -> 300], 
 Background -> None] & /@ Range[10]
```

Picture against white and red background:

[image: Transparent rectangle]

Comment: Thank you I was not aware of "Transparent". I Would really like to have the White Rectangle, the first in the Graphics[] Transparent instead, keeping its edge. Is it possible ? I have not been able to apply it to one object only.

Comment: @500, does the edited version work?

Comment: @kguler.Perfectly, Thank you again.