# Generate Random Text within a Rectangle

Tags: graphics, random, text

I would like to generate images such as the four below.

That is: some text of different length fit within a `Rectangle[]` using `Graphics[]`.

But I don't know how to "go to the next line" at the edge of the `Rectangle[]`.

The text could either be a random length of "Lorem Ipsum" or alternatively some random text:

[image]

---

**EDIT**

Provided kguler figured out my plan, here it is: I need to fit the text as below. I have yet not been able to place any solution well in my Graphics[], code below.

[image]

```
c0 = {RGBColor[23/85, 29/255, 142/255], RGBColor[244/255, 1, 59/255], 
      RGBColor[1, 0, 32/85], RGBColor[18/85, 72/85, 197/255]}


Graphics[{
  EdgeForm[Thickness[.005]], White,
  Rectangle[{0, 0}, {160, 90}],
  Black, Opacity[.7],
  Rectangle[{0, 0}, {80, 63}],
  Opacity[1],
  Flatten@({Flatten@(Table[
       RandomChoice[{GrayLevel[.15], c0[[#]]}], {3}] & /@ 
     Range[2, 4, 1]),
  MapThread[
   Function[{Xs, Ys},
    Rectangle[{Xs, Ys}, {Xs + 16, Ys + 9}]],
   {Flatten@Table[Range[0, 32, 16], {3}], 
    Flatten@(Table[#, {3}] & /@ 
       Range[63, 81, 9])}]}\[Transpose]),
  Black, Thickness[.005], Line[{{0, 63}, {159, 63}}]}, 
  Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> True},
  ImageSize -> 500]
```

Comment: Note: Lorem ipsum is available through `ExampleData[{"Text", "LoremIpsum"}]`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe something like this (using `Inset` and `Pane` to place text inside the rectangle):

```
txdt = ExampleData[{"Text", "LoremIpsum"}]; 
Manipulate[Graphics[{EdgeForm[Thick], Opacity[0], Rectangle[{0, 0}, {160, 90}], 
Opacity[1], 
Inset[Pane[
 Style[txdt, TextAlignment -> Left], {Scaled[1], Scaled[.75]}, 
 Alignment -> Center,
 Scrollbars -> Automatic, AppearanceElements -> {"ResizeArea"}, 
 ImageSizeAction -> "Scrollable"], {left, bottom}, {Left, 
 Bottom}, {right - left, top - bottom}], 
 Flatten@({Flatten@(Table[
        RandomChoice[{GrayLevel[.15], c0[[#]]}], {3}] & /@ 
      Range[2, 4, 1]), 
   MapThread[Function[{Xs, Ys}, 
     Rectangle[{Xs, Ys}, {Xs + 16, Ys + 9}]], {Flatten@
      Table[Range[0, 32, 16], {3}], 
     Flatten@(Table[#, {3}] & /@ 
        Range[63, 81, 9])}]}\[Transpose]), Black, Thick, 
 Line[{{0, 63}, {160, 63}}]}, PlotRange -> {{0, 160}, {0, 90}}, 
 ImageSize -> 400], {{left, 0}, 0, 140, 1}, {{bottom, 0}, 0, 55, 1}, 
 {{right, 160}, 10, 160, 1}, {{top, 75}, 0, 75, 1}]
```

With output:

[image: manipulate to place text inside graphics rectangle]:

**Source:** Inset trick based on `TextRect` courtesy of Wolfram's John Fultz: pls see    [MathGroup](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2010/Jun/msg00307.html)

EDIT: Without assuming that the current question is related to 
[OP`s previous question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1224/125), using just plain rectangles and text:

```
 Graphics[{EdgeForm[Thick], Opacity[0], Rectangle[{0, 0}, {160, 90}], 
   Opacity[1], 
   Inset[Pane[Style[#, 12, TextAlignment -> Left], {Scaled[1], 
      Scaled[.75]}, Alignment -> Center, Scrollbars -> Automatic, 
     AppearanceElements -> {"ResizeArea"}, 
     ImageSizeAction -> "Scrollable"], {5, 5}, {Left, 
     Bottom}, {150, 100}]}, PlotRange -> {{0, 160}, {0, 90}}, 
  ImageSize -> 400] &@
  RandomChoice@Take[ExampleData[{"Text", "LoremIpsum"}, "Lines"], 
  {1,-1,2}] & /@    Range@4 // Grid[Partition[#, 2]] &
```

which gives

[image: random text in rectangles]

If the rectangles are known to be large enough so that scrolling will not be needed, then `Pane` is not needed; you can use the following version of the `Inset`:

```
 Inset[Style[Text[#], 12, TextAlignment -> Left], {5, 90}, {Left, 
   Top}, {150, 100}]
```

EDIT 2: Putting the text in the proper rectangle (in response the OPs edit), using `txt1` from `Lorem Ipsum`

```
 txt1 = Take[ExampleData[{"Text", "LoremIpsum"}, "Lines"], {1, -1, 2}][[1]] //
 StringTake[#, 330] & ;
```

in

```
 Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Thickness[0.005`], Black}], White, 
 Rectangle[{0, 0}, {160, 90}], Black, Opacity[0.7`], 
 EdgeForm[{Thickness[0.005`], Black}], Rectangle[{0, 0}, {80, 63}], 
 Inset[Pane[
 Style[txt1, 12, TextAlignment -> Left], {Scaled[1], 
 Scaled[0.75`]}, Alignment -> Center, 
 ImageSizeAction -> "Scrollable"], {0, 8}, {Left, Bottom}, {78, 
 67}], Flatten[
 Transpose[{Flatten[(Table[
      RandomChoice[{GrayLevel[0.15`], c0[[#1]]}], {3}] &) /@ 
   Range[2, 4, 1]], 
 MapThread[
  Function[{Xs, Ys}, 
   Rectangle[{Xs, Ys}, {Xs + 16, Ys + 9}]], {Flatten[
    Table[Range[0, 32, 16], {3}]], 
   Flatten[(Table[#1, {3}] &) /@ Range[63, 81, 9]]}]}]], Null, 
Black, Thickness[0.005`], Line[{{0, 63}, {159, 63}}]}, 
PlotRange -> {{0, 160}, {0, 90}}, Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> True}, 
ImagePadding -> 2, ImageMargins -> 0, ImageSize -> 500]
```

you get

[image: text in rectangle]

Comment: Thank You very much for your solution and guessing my problem. Not been able yet to use it as in my edit avoiding the little sign on the lower left of the pane. Well not been able to place it accurately neither :-(

Comment: @500, hope the new edit is close to what you need.

Comment: Looks perfect ! Where did you define txt1 ?

Comment: @500, just added the definition of `txt1`.

Comment: Thank You very much. Is your solution compatible with the one to place an image on the other side  : http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1254/fit-an-image-within-a-rectangle-in-graphics  I have yet not been able to combine the two :-(

Comment: @500, Heike already combined the two in her answer to your other question. That leaves one more pane to fill in your canvas; I am afraid to guess that you will need some controls and buttons there:)

Comment: still a little problem with his solution. When exporting I get only a few lines... I need this for a presentation in 2 hours :-) I will explain what it is after !

Comment: @500, sorry just noticed your last comment. From the timestamps of the comments on your other question, looks like Heike solved this issue too. Hope all pieces are working together fine now.

Comment: Yes, thank you for all your support !

Answer (score 12):

Rather than using a `Rectangle`, consider a [`Pane`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Pane.html) that is `Framed`

```
text = "Bunch of random text ";

Framed@Pane[StringJoin @@ Table[text, {10}], 300]
```

[image]

The second argument to `Pane` determines the width in points.

If you want more control over the text within the `Pane`, consider putting a `TextCell` inside the `Pane`. If you just use a `TextCell`, you can't control its width.

```
Framed@Pane[TextCell[StringJoin @@ Table[text, {10}], 13, 
  TextJustification -> 0], 300]
```

[image]

I appreciate that my proposed solution isn't a `Graphics` object, but it gives you the desired result. The question is whether you need this in a `Graphics` object or not.

Comment: you could `Rasterize` it.

Comment: Also to control the frame thickness (he uses thick lines) instead of Framed[...] we can do Grid[{{...}}, Frame -> All, FrameStyle -> Directive[Thickness[5], Brown]]

Comment: @Verbeia, Thank You very much. Please see my Edit if you can help me place your solution in my exact context :-) ?