# Fit an image within a Rectangle [] in Graphics

Tags: graphics, image-processing

Based on the following Code (yet the white text in the image is added with PPT), I would like to have an image fit within one of the rectangle.

For Example the image from there :

http://dailytechgadgets.files.wordpress.com/2011/02/old-ferrari.jpg

2 main problem :

Although I know about Texture[], I have not been able to use it in my rectangle, nor drawing the correct polygon, or the correct vertex coordinates.

The image might not be of the same ratio, so I would like to crop it accordingly. I have not been able to yet without deforming the image.

My Ideal OutPut below :

[image]

```
c0 = {RGBColor[23/85, 29/255, 142/255], RGBColor[244/255, 1, 59/255], 
      RGBColor[1, 0, 32/85], RGBColor[18/85, 72/85, 197/255]}

Graphics[{EdgeForm[Thickness[.005]], White, 
 Rectangle[{0, 0}, {160, 90}], Black, Opacity[.7], 
 Rectangle[{0, 0}, {80, 63}], White, Opacity[1], 
 Rectangle[{80, 0}, {160, 63}], Opacity[1], 
 Flatten@({Flatten@(Table[
       RandomChoice[{GrayLevel[.15], c0[[#]]}], {3}] & /@ 
     Range[2, 4, 1]), 
  MapThread[
   Function[{Xs, Ys}, 
    Rectangle[{Xs, Ys}, {Xs + 16, Ys + 9}]], {Flatten@
     Table[Range[0, 32, 16], {3}], 
    Flatten@(Table[#, {3}] & /@ 
       Range[63, 81, 9])}]}\[Transpose])}, 
 Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> True}, ImageSize -> 500]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What about this to create the textured rectangle. Here, `pic` is the picture you want to use for the `Texture` and `ll` and `ur` are the lower left and upper right corners of the box.

```
rec[ll_, ur_, pic_] := Module[{crop, boxrat},
  boxrat = #2/#1 & @@ MapThread[Abs[#2 - #1] &, {ll, ur}];
  crop = ImageCrop[pic, Transpose[{ ImageDimensions[pic]}], 
    AspectRatio -> boxrat];

  {Texture[ImageData[crop]],
   Polygon[Tuples[Sort /@ Transpose[{ll, ur}]][[{1, 2, 4, 3}]],
    VertexTextureCoordinates -> Tuples[{0, 1}, 2][[{1, 2, 4, 3}]]]}]
```

For your example you would get

```
pic = Import[
      "http://dailytechgadgets.files.wordpress.com/2011/02/old-ferrari.jpg"];

Graphics[{EdgeForm[Thickness[.005]], White, 
  Rectangle[{0, 0}, {160, 90}], Black, Opacity[.7], 
  Rectangle[{0, 0}, {80, 63}], White, Opacity[1],

  rec[{80, 0}, {160, 63}, pic], Opacity[1], 

  Flatten@({Flatten@(Table[
        RandomChoice[{GrayLevel[.15], c0[[#]]}], {3}] & /@ Range[2, 4, 1]), 
    MapThread[
     Function[{Xs, Ys}, 
       Rectangle[{Xs, Ys}, {Xs + 16, Ys + 9}]], {Flatten@
         Table[Range[0, 32, 16], {3}], 
       Flatten@(Table[#, {3}] & /@ 
           Range[63, 81, 9])}]}\[Transpose])}, 
 Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> True}, ImageSize -> 500]
```

which produces

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Edit**

Instead of cropping the image first and using that as the texture you can also play around with the settings for `VertexTextureCoordinates`. For example you could also do

```
rec2[ll_, ur_, pic_, f_:.5] := 
 Module[{boxrat, picrat},
  picrat = #2/#1 & @@ ImageDimensions[pic];
  boxrat = #2/#1 & @@ MapThread[Abs[#2 - #1] &, {ll, ur}];
  {Texture[ImageData[pic]],
   Polygon[Tuples[Sort /@ Transpose[{ll, ur}]][[{1, 2, 4, 3}]], 
    VertexTextureCoordinates -> 
     Tuples[{ 
       {f Max[0, 1 - picrat/boxrat], 1 - (1-f) Max[0, 1- picrat/boxrat]}, 
       {f Max[0, 1 - boxrat/picrat], 1 - (1-f) Max[0, 1- boxrat/picrat]}}]
         [[{1, 2, 4, 3}]]]}]
```

I've added an extra argument `f` which indicates which indicates how much of the left or right of the image should be cropped. For example a setting of `0` would indicate that all cropping should be from the right side of the image (or the top depending on the aspect ration of the image). When `f==0.5` equal parts are cropped from the left and right sides and when `f==1` the image is only cropped on the left side (or bottom).

**Edit 2**

It looks like `Texture` isn't playing nicely with `Inset` used in kguler's answer to your previous. To get the text and the image in the same picture you could do something like this instead

```
rec[ll_, ur_, pic_] := Module[{crop, boxrat},
  boxrat = #2/#1 & @@ MapThread[Abs[#2 - #1] &, {ll, ur}];
  crop = ImageCrop[pic, Transpose[{ ImageDimensions[pic]}],
    AspectRatio -> boxrat];
  Inset[crop, Min /@ Transpose[{ll, ur}], {Left, Bottom}, 
   Abs[ur - ll]]]
```

Combined with [kguler's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1240/46) you get something like

```
Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Thickness[0.005`], Black}],
   FaceForm[White], Rectangle[{0, 0}, {160, 90}],
   FaceForm[Darker[Gray]], Rectangle[{0, 0}, {80, 63}],

   (* code for picture *)
   {rec[{80, 0}, {160, 63}, pic],
    FaceForm[Opacity[0]],
    Rectangle[{80, 0}, {160, 63}]},

   (* code for text *)
   Inset[Pane[
     Style[txt1, 12, TextAlignment -> Left], {Scaled[1], 
      Scaled[0.75`]}, Alignment -> Center, 
     ImageSizeAction -> "Scrollable"], {0, 8}, {Left, Bottom}, {78, 
     67}],

   Flatten[
    Transpose[{Flatten[(Table[
           RandomChoice[{GrayLevel[0.15`], c0[[#1]]}], {3}] &) /@ 
        Range[2, 4, 1]], 
      MapThread[
       Function[{Xs, Ys}, 
        Rectangle[{Xs, Ys}, {Xs + 16, Ys + 9}]], {Flatten[
         Table[Range[0, 32, 16], {3}]], 
        Flatten[(Table[#1, {3}] &) /@ Range[63, 81, 9]]}]}]],
   {Black, Thickness[0.005`], Line[{{0, 63}, {159, 63}}]}}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 160}, {0, 90}}, Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> True}, 
  ImagePadding -> 2, ImageMargins -> 0, ImageSize -> 500]
```

which produces something like

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: thank You very much, is this solution compatible with the one of kguler in http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1229/generate-random-text-within-a-rectangle   I cannot assemble your 2 solutions to have both in one Graphics []

Comment: @500 see updated answer

Comment: thank You very much for your attention. When i try to export it, I get only one line of the text. And on the output within the .nb, I need to click to see the text appear. Any idea how to fix this ?

Comment: @500 Are you using the updated version of `rec`? I got the behaviour you described with the previous one using `Texture` but not with the newest one using `Inset`. Maybe you need to run `Clear[rec]` first to clear the old definition. As for exporting, to what format are you exporting?

Answer (score 1):

I would use something along these lines, (borrowing from an [earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7135572/2-column-documents-in-mathematica/7138184#7138184)).

The test image, House2, is clipped, then set into the main graphic.

```
block1 = Graphics[{Red, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {150, 210}]}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 150}, {0, 210}}];

block2 = Graphics[{Blue, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {150, 210}]}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 150}, {0, 210}}];

image = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "House2"}];

clippedimage = 
  Graphics[{Green, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {500, 270}], 
    Inset[image, {250, 170}, {Center, Center}, {512, 512}]}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 500}, {0, 270}}, ImageSize -> 500];

Graphics[{Yellow, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {330, 400}], 
  Inset[block1, {75, 295}, {Center, Center}, {150, 210}], 
  Inset[block2, {255, 295}, {Center, Center}, {150, 210}], 
  Inset[clippedimage, {165, 90}, {Center, Center}, {330, 179}]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 330}, {0, 400}}, ImageSize -> 330]
```

[image]