# Rectangle with rounded edges

Tags: graphics, image

Inspired from :

[Fit an image within a Rectangle [] in Graphics](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1254/fit-an-image-within-a-rectangle-in-graphics)

I would like now to fit an image within a Rectangle[] with **rounded edges** as shown in the example below :

[image]

Is it possible ?

Comment: You need to use `RoundingRadius` as an option in `Rectangle` like `Graphics[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {2, 1}, RoundingRadius -> 0.3]]`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using pieces from the linked answers, and Heike's code:

Text piece:

```
 txt1 = Take[
 ExampleData[{"Text", "LoremIpsum"}, "Lines"], {1, -1, 2}][[1]] //
 StringTake[#, 330] &;
```

Image piece:

```
 pic = Import["http://dailytechgadgets.files.wordpress.com/2011/02/old-ferrari.jpg"];
```

And Heike's code for rectangles:

```
 rec[ll_, ur_, pic_] := 
 Module[{crop, boxrat}, 
 boxrat = #2/#1 & @@ MapThread[Abs[#2 - #1] &, {ll, ur}]; 
 crop = ImageCrop[pic, Transpose[{ImageDimensions[pic]}], 
 AspectRatio -> boxrat]; 
 Inset[crop, Min /@ Transpose[{ll, ur}], {Left, Bottom}, 
 Abs[ur - ll]]]
```

and Heike's code again for putting all together -- just adding `RoundingRadius` to rectangle objects and commenting out lines that produce lines--:

```
 Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Thickness[0.005`], Black}], FaceForm[White], 
 Rectangle[{0, 0}, {160, 90}, RoundingRadius -> 4], 
 FaceForm[Darker[Gray]], 
 Rectangle[{0, 0}, {80, 63}, 
 RoundingRadius -> 4],(*code for picture*){rec[{80, 0}, {160, 63}, 
 pic], FaceForm[Opacity[0]], 
 Rectangle[{80, 0}, {160, 63}, 
 RoundingRadius -> 4]},(*code for text*)
 Inset[Pane[
 Style[txt1, 12, TextAlignment -> Left], {Scaled[1], 
 Scaled[0.75`]}, Alignment -> Center, 
 ImageSizeAction -> "Scrollable"], {0, 8}, {Left, Bottom}, {78,67}], 
 Flatten[Transpose[{Flatten[(Table[
      RandomChoice[{GrayLevel[0.15`], c0[[#1]]}], {3}] &) /@ 
   Range[2, 4, 1]], 
 MapThread[
  Function[{Xs, Ys}, 
   Rectangle[{Xs, Ys}, {Xs + 16, Ys + 9}, 
    RoundingRadius -> 4]], {Flatten[Table[Range[0, 32, 16], {3}]],
    Flatten[(Table[#1, {3}] &) /@ Range[63, 81, 9]]}]}]](*,{Black,
 Thickness[0.005`],Line[{{0,63},{159,63}}]}*)}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 160}, {0, 90}}, Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> True}, 
 ImagePadding -> 2, ImageMargins -> 0, ImageSize -> 500]
```

produces:

[image: image output]

You need further refinements to clean up. 
In particular, the image needs to be masked with a rectangle with rounded corners.

EDIT: For masking an image with a round-cornered reactangle, play with the parameters of `Rectangle` in

```
 pic2 = ImageAdd[ pic, 
 Graphics[{Black, Rectangle[{2, 1}, {4, 2}, RoundingRadius -> .2]}]]
```

**Update:** For better masking using `SetAlphaChannel` and better handling of image size (Thanks: @ssch and @Jens)

```
roundImage[img_, r_] := Module[{dim = ImageDimensions[img], sr}, 
sr = Max[dim]*r; 
SetAlphaChannel[img, 
   Graphics[{White, Rectangle[Scaled[{0, 0}], Scaled[{1, 1}], RoundingRadius -> sr]},
 Background -> Black, PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 0}, dim}\[Transpose], AspectRatio -> Automatic] ]]
```

Comment: In case you want to layer these rectangles on top of other graphics, it may be a slight improvement to change the masking procedure to an actual alpha mask by doing something like this:  pic2 = SetAlphaChannel[pic, 
  Graphics[{White, Rectangle[{2, 1}, {4, 2}, RoundingRadius -> .2]}, Background -> Black, PlotRangePadding -> None]] (you'll see the difference only if you display the result with a background.

Comment: I made a function to automate the handling of image size:

`roundImage[img_, r_] := Module[{dim = ImageDimensions[img], sr},
  sr = Max[dim]*r;
  SetAlphaChannel[img,
   Graphics[{White, 
     Rectangle[Scaled[{0, 0}], Scaled[{1, 1}], 
      RoundingRadius -> sr]},
    Background -> Black,
    PlotRangePadding -> 0,
    PlotRange -> {{0, 0}, dim}\[Transpose],
    AspectRatio -> Automatic]
   ]]`

Comment: @ssch and Jens,thank you both. Will update with your suggestions.

Answer (score 6):

You can also use `Framed` to frame e.g. `Text` elements in your graphics, which also takes the `RoundingRadius` option. The size of the resulting rounded frame is depending on the text (or other) element.

A quick´n dirty version of your theme could be:

```
Framed[Row[{Framed[Style[Text[" $ "], 40, Bold, Magenta], 
    RoundingRadius -> 5], "                        "}], 
 RoundingRadius -> 5, FrameMargins -> -1]
```

[image]

or within a `Graphics` context:

```
Graphics[Text[
    Framed[Style["Hello!", RandomReal[{2, 20}]], RoundingRadius -> 10,
      Background -> 
      Directive[Hue[RandomReal[]], Opacity[RandomReal[]]]], #] & /@ 
  RandomReal[{0, 1}, {50, 2}], ImageSize -> 480]
```

[image]

Comment: In fact, there is a bit of colour bleeding over the black outline at the lower and right edges which does not seem to appear with rounded rectangles (as in kguler´s answer). Otherwise the rounding works nicely.