# How to create a multi-graphics plot (i.e. the decomposition of phase plane portrait) with well-organized structure?

Tags: plotting, graphics, grid-layouts

**Background**

I am trying to create a three-graphics plot using the command `GraphicsGrid[]` to show the decomposition of the phase plane portrait; unfortunately, the plot created is very ugly since the axes of each graph are not aligned with each other; besides, the corresponding step size of the axes are not identical.

**Sources**

The differential equation of the dynamic system is given below:

```
f1 = {y''[t] ==  -9.82 Sin[y[t]] + 1.5 (y[t] - y'[t]), y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 0};

ss[t_] = NDSolve[f1, y, {t, 0, 10}]
```

**Questions**

1. How to create a multi-graphics plot with axes aligned well automatically?
2. How to make sure the step sizes of the axes are consistent with the corresponding axes of different graphics?

[image]

**Updates**

I have tried the solution (specifing the PlotRange and ImageSize of the graphic) offered by @Sumit, which works well in certain situation; however, the questions aforementioned still remain, shown as following:
[image]

the associated codes are given as:

```
(*differenital equation:*)
f1 = {y''[t] ==  -9.82 Sin[y[t]] + 1.5 (y[t] - y'[t]), y[0] == 1,  y'[0] == 0};
ss[t_] = NDSolve[f1, y, {t, 0, 10}];
(*Graph 1: yy*)
yyt = Plot[y[t] /. ss[t], {t, 0, 10}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {-0.5, 1.5}}, ImageSize -> {360, 226}, 
   AxesLabel -> {"t", "\[Theta]"}];
yy = Rotate[yyt, -0.5 \[Pi]];
(*Graph 2: Dy*)
Dy = Plot[y'[t] /. ss[t], {t, 0, 10}, 
    PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {-2, 1}},
    ImageSize -> {360, 245},  
    AxesLabel -> {"t", "\!\(\*FractionBox[\(d\[Theta]\), \(dt\)]\)"}];
(*Graph 3: yyDy--the phase plane portrait*)
yyDy = ParametricPlot[{y[t], y'[t]} /. ss[t], {t, 0, 10}, 
   PlotRange -> {{-0.5, 1.5}, {-2, 1}}, ImageSize -> {226, 245}, 
   AxesLabel -> {"\[Theta]", 
     "\!\(\*FractionBox[\(d\[Theta]\), \(dt\)]\)"}];
(*Create the multi-graphics plot*)
Grid[{{yyDy, Dy}, {yy}}]
```

Comment: Related: [(4059)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4059/121), [(6877)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6877/121), [(13373)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13373/121), [(17285)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17285/121), [(37465)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/37465/121)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using same `PlotRange` would be a good start. For example

```
x[t_] = t Sin[t];
y[t_] = t Cos[t];
plot1 = ParametricPlot[{x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotRange -> {{-6, 6}, {-6, 6}},
        AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}];
plot2 = ParametricPlot[{t, x[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotRange -> {{-6, 6}, {-6, 6}},
        AxesLabel -> {"t", "x"}];
plot3 = ParametricPlot[{y[t], t}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotRange -> {{-6, 6}, {-6, 6}}, 
        AxesLabel -> {"y", "t"}];

Grid[{{plot3,}, {plot1, plot2}}]
```

[image]

You can do further adjustment by `ImageSize`, `ImageMargins`, `FrameMargins` etc.

### Manual Adjust

Let's start from

```
f1 = {y''[t] == -9.82 Sin[y[t]] + 1.5 (y[t] - y'[t]), y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 0};
ss[t_] = y[t] /. NDSolve[f1, y, {t, 0, 10}][[1]];

pl1 = ParametricPlot[{ss[t], ss'[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotRange -> {{-0.4, 0.4}, {-2, 1}}, 
      AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> 200, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}];
pl2 = ParametricPlot[{ss[t], t}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotRange -> {{-0.4, 0.4}, {0, 6}}, 
      AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> 200, AxesLabel -> {"x", "t"}];
pl3 = ParametricPlot[{t, ss'[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotRange -> {{0, 6}, {-2, 1}}, 
      AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> 200, AxesLabel -> {"t", "y"}];
```

Since you are using similar `PlotRange` simple `Grid` should work nicely. If you need to do some manual adjustment, use `Manipulate` to find best `ImagePadding` and then use the final output `plotall`.

```
Manipulate[
p1 = Show[pl1, ImagePadding -> b0];
p2 = Show[pl2, ImagePadding -> {{bx1, bx2}, {b0, b0}}];
p3 = Show[pl3, ImagePadding -> {{b0, b0}, {by1, by2}}];
plotall = Grid[{{p2,}, {p1, p3}}, Spacings -> 0],
{{b0, 20}, 0, 100},
{{bx1, 20}, 0, 100}, {{bx2, 20}, 0, 100},
{{by1, 20}, 0, 100}, {{by2, 20}, 0, 100}]

plotall
```

[image]

Comment: if the PlotRange of v and h-axes of each plot must be specified differently, how to fix the problem?

Answer (score 15):

```
f1 = {y''[t] == -9.82 Sin[y[t]] + 1.5 (y[t] - y'[t]), y[0] == 1, 
   y'[0] == 0};
ss[t_] = y[t] /. NDSolve[f1, y, {t, 0, 10}][[1]]
fun[p_] := 
 Show[Plot[ss'[t - 1], {t, 1, 2 Pi + 1}, PlotRange -> Full], 
  ParametricPlot[{ss[t], ss'[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}],
  ParametricPlot[{ss[t - 2], -t}, {t, 2, 2 Pi + 2}]
  , PlotRange -> {{-1, 6}, {-8, 1}}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
  GridLines -> {{ss[p]}, {ss'[p]}}, 
  Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], 
    Point[{{ss[p], ss'[p]}, {p + 1, ss'[p]}, {ss[p], -p - 2}}]}]
```

Animated gif from table of `fun[p]`:

[image]

Comment: could the top-right and bottom-left graphics be plotted seperately with their own axes and labels?

Comment: @Liang.X  I did this to make alignment work (as demonstrated) by grid lines. You could customize ticks to give 'correct' values of t. I leave that to you. Happy holidays:)