# Manipulation of Automatic settings in a given case

Tags: graphics, options

Often I use the `Automatic` option to specify plot styles, plot ranges, image sizes, etc.
I'd like to be able to apply some modifications to these automatically defined values.
For example, if a plot with the `PlotRange -> Automatic` would draw the function on the interval $[0,1]$, I'd like to be able to use something like `PlotRange -> #*2 & /@ Automatic` to extend the plot range to $[0,2]$.
Is this possible in general, or maybe every case would need a specific solution?

*I'm not sure what tags are most appropriate for this topic, please add them if you think they're more suitable than the one I've chosen.*

Comment: Does something like `PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[0.25]` do what you're after?

Comment: It works in this particular case, but not with `Automatic` in general. `Automatic` can be a single number, a list or array of numbers, a color rule, some other styling directive, a method used in computation of a function...

Comment: It makes sense with something like `PlotRange`, but I can't imagine what `Method -> 2*Automatic` or `f@Automatic` would mean, that wouldn't be clearer with an explicit setting.

Answer (score 3):

My dirty, as usual, post-processing solution

```
Row@{
  Plot[Sin@x, {x, 0, Pi}, PlotRange -> Automatic, ImageSize -> 300],
  Plot[Sin@x, {x, 0, Pi}, PlotRange -> Automatic, ImageSize -> 300] /. 
    x : Rule[PlotRange, __] :> Rule[PlotRange, ({#1, 2 #2} & @@ x[[2]])]}
```

[image]

One could simplify replacement rule, then it could be started to be considered some kind of solution.

Comment: Yes, this is something I'm looking for. I'm going to play with it a bit.

Comment: @shrx Please report if You manage to shorten replacement rule. I'm glad You like it.

Comment: This will not work in all cases.  `AbsoluteOptions` is more reliable (though far from foolproof, it has plenty of inconsistencies)

Comment: I should have of course given an example when it does not work: `Graphics[Circle[], PlotRange -> Automatic]`

Comment: @Szabolcs Of course I agree. I should have put some more effort to describe limitations of this method.

Answer (score 3):

This is a rather common annoyance.  In the case of most functions, there is no *general* way to find out what an `Automatic` setting does---you'd have to check the docs for it.

In the case of `Graphics` object however (what most plotting functions produce), you can typically use `AbsoluteOptions` to retrieve the actual numerical value of the setting.

For example, let's take

```
g = Graphics[Circle[], PlotRange -> Automatic] (* the default option value is PlotRange -> All *)
```

Now `Options[g, PlotRange]` just return `Automatic`.  `AbsoluteOptions[g, PlotRange]` returns `PlotRange -> {{-1., 1.}, {-1., 1.}}`.

Once you have the value of the option, you can use `Show` to create a version of the graphics object with a modified value:

```
pr = PlotRange /. AbsoluteOptions[g, PlotRange]
Show[g, PlotRange -> 2 pr]
```

---

Unfortunately `AbsoluteOptions` is not entirely reliable, especially with options controlling padding and margins.  See for example [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2091/retrieving-the-imagepadding-in-absolute-units).  It is the first thing you should try though.

Also take a look at `FullGraphics` with the caveat that its output is typically just an approximation, and may not correspond to the input completely.  It still has [good uses](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2030/12) though.

Comment: It's strange that `AbsoluteOptions` work for `Plot` but not for `PolarPlot`.

Comment: @shrx I'd call that a `PolarPlot` bug.  I think the form `PlotRange -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Automatic, Automatic}}` is incorrect.  You could report this.  You can work around it by using `Show` to correct the option value on the `PolatPlot` output.