# Prevent Grid from resizing images

Tags: graphics, front-end, grid-layouts

Aligning my images in `Grid` causes one of them to become smaller, despite specifying each of their sizes with `ImageSize`:

```
dat = Table[{x, y, RandomReal[]*x*y}, {x, 1, 50}, {y, 1, 50}];
img = ListContourPlot[Flatten[dat, 1], ImageSize -> {300, 300}];
oldspotlight = 
  Graphics[{}, Background -> Black, PlotRange -> {{1, 50}, {1, 50}}, 
   ImageSize -> 300];
a=Show[img, 
 Graphics[{Circle[{90, 60}, 10]}, PlotRange -> {{1, 50}, {1, 50}}, 
  ImageSize -> {300, 300}]]
b=ImageMultiply[img, 
 ImageAdd[oldspotlight, 
  Graphics[{ColorData["GrayTones"][10/20], Disk[{90, 60}, 10]}, 
   Background -> Black, PlotRange -> {{1, 50}, {1, 50}}, 
   ImageSize -> {300, 300}]]]
Grid[{{a,b}}]
```

Output:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Please note that I don't want to use `GraphicsGrid`.  (The reason is because it doesn't cooperate with `Dynamic`, which is an unrelated question.)

Comment: If you could find a simple that example that still has this problem, it would be easier to help. Right now there is a lot of code, but most of it is unrelated to your problem.

Comment: `Anon`:  I made the code a little simpler

Comment: Curious. From the documentation: `Grid will not change the size of graphics or other objects that have explicit ImageSize settings. `

Comment: Does `Row[{img, oldspotlight}]` do what you want? It does not resize.

Comment: Sorry @bill s, for the non-minimum working example, but I would want `Row[{a,b}]`, which worsens the problem

Comment: I don't have this problem in version 7 under Windows.  What version/OS are you using?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Mathematica 9.0.0.0 on Windows XP SP3

Comment: Can anyone say if this happens in version 8?  It may be a v9 bug.

Comment: Take a look at [SciDraw](http://scidraw.nd.edu/). [It makes it much easier to create grids with alignment](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/37880/12), even complex layouts [like this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ieEf4.png).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it, which would be a minimal change to your current code, is just wrap image `b` in `Show` as you did with image `a` and give the `ImageSize` option to this second `Show`.

```
dat = Table[{x, y, RandomReal[]*x*y}, {x, 1, 50}, {y, 1, 50}];
img = ListContourPlot[Flatten[dat, 1], ImageSize -> {300, 300}];
oldspotlight = 
  Graphics[{}, Background -> Black, PlotRange -> {{1, 50}, {1, 50}}, 
   ImageSize -> 300];
a = Show[img, 
  Graphics[{Circle[{90, 60}, 10]}, PlotRange -> {{1, 50}, {1, 50}}, 
   ImageSize -> {300, 300}]];
b = Show[ImageMultiply[img, 
   ImageAdd[oldspotlight, 
    Graphics[{ColorData["GrayTones"][10/20], Disk[{90, 60}, 10]}, 
     Background -> White, PlotRange -> {{1, 50}, {1, 50}}]]], 
  ImageSize -> {300, 300}];
Grid[{{a, b}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

### [ImageSizeMultiplers](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ImageSizeMultipliers.html)

> - ImageSizeMultipliers 
>     *is an option that specifies how much smaller to render graphics that appear within other constructs.*
> - ImageSizeMultipliers -> {u,v} *specifies that graphics inside list-like constructs should be u times their normal size, while graphics inside function-like constructs should be v times their normal size.*
> - *A typical default setting for* ImageSizeMultipliers *is {0.5, 0.25}.*

So we can use

```
Style[Grid[{{a, b}}], ImageSizeMultipliers -> {1, 1}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

How about using `Row`:

```
Row[{img, "  ", oldspotlight}]
```

or

```
Row[{a, "  ", Image[b, ImageSize -> 300]}]
```

both of which give:

[image]

(I added the `" "` to make some space between them).

Comment: I wish I could also accept this as the answer!