# Define spacings for Grid when exporting

Tags: graphics, export, grid-layouts

I want to combine graphics and non-graphics items in a `Grid` and export the result to an image file (e.g., png). There are good reasons not to use `GraphicsGrid`, see, e.g., [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15356/make-legend-same-height-as-plot/132951#132951) and [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/38832/prevent-grid-from-resizing-images) post. But how can I control the vertical spacing between the rows? Here is one example:

```
im = Grid[{{1, 2, 3}, {Graphics[Circle[]], Graphics[Circle[]], 
    Graphics[Circle[]]}, {4, 5, 6}}, Spacings -> {0, 0}]
```

Looks good in the notebook:

[image]

but not when I export it

```
Export["test.png", im, ImageResolution -> 500];
```

[image]

How can I export it just as it is shown in the notebook?

I tried:

```
Export["/home/felix/test.png", im, ImageResolution -> 500, 
  ImageSize -> {2000, 1000}, AspectRatio -> 1/2];
```

yielding a distorted image and `AspectRatio` has no effect:

[image]

Comment: This appears to be a problem with `Magnify`, or at least that function also exhibits the problem.

Comment: You are right, any value larger `3` in `Magnify[im, 3]` leads to the same distortion. Similarly, `ImageResolution->200` works fine, `ImageResolution->300` doesn't. As a workaround, is there another way to "magnify" the result to obtain a decent resolution without running into this problem?

Comment: Have you tried setting `ImageSizeMultipliers -> 1` and/or playing with `ItemSize`? Providing explicit `ImageSize` for every `Graphics`?

Answer (score 3):

[`Magnify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Magnify.html) also exhibits the problem, e.g.

```
ImageResize[Rasterize @ Magnify[im, 5], 400]
```

[image]

This seems to be related to [The mysterious gap inside Grid](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/52185/121).

Since `Grid` does not work correctly with the built-in method to rescale arbitrary expressions (`Magnify`) I can only suggest rasterizing the individual grid elements:

```
rasterize[rez_] := 
  Show[Rasterize[#, "Image", ImageResolution -> rez], Magnification -> 1] &;

rasterGrid[Grid[a_, x___], rez_] := Grid[Map[rasterize[rez], a, {2}], x]
```

Test:

```
Export["testgrid.png", rasterGrid[im, 300]];

Import["testgrid.png"]
```

[image]

```
Import["testgrid.png"] // ImageDimensions
```

> ```
> {4500, 1679}
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Based on Mr. Wizard's observation that the issue is with `Magnify`, one more option is to export and re-import to a vector graphics format:

```
im2 = ImportString[ExportString[im, "pdf"]];
Export["test.png", im2, ImageResolution -> 500];
```

[image]

If there are no issues with the pdf export, then the new `im2` image can be exported with any resolution. Sometimes, I have the magnify issue also with the pdf export, which I found can be solved by setting `ItemSize` in the grid explicitly (to small values).

Comment: Good solution!  I have exported to PDF and then converted to images outside of *Mathematica* to handle other glitches; reimporting the Graphics is a nice touch and much more handy.