# Export 3d plot: BoxStyle->Thick does not scale with ImageResolution

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, export

Consider this simple 3d figure:

```
plot = Plot3D[100,
  {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, .4},
  PlotRange -> {{0, 3}, {0, .4}, {0, 100}},
  BoxRatios -> {3, .4, .5},
  ViewPoint -> {0, -Pi, 1.3},
  ImageSize -> {710, 220},
  AxesStyle -> Thick,
  BoxStyle -> Thick,
  Mesh -> None
  ]
```

Exporting it with "native" resolution results in a homogeneous thickness of all box lines:

```
Export["test.png", plot];
```

[image]

However, when increasing the image resolution, the axis thickness scales properly by the box lines don't:

```
Export["test.png", plot, ImageResolution -> 200];
```

[image]

[The known ticks issue](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/51367/export-high-resolution-figure-causes-missing-ticks) seems related but not the same. Also, exporting to PDF is often not an option for 3d graphics because [the files are huge](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1542/exporting-graphics-to-pdf-huge-file). Any workaround for this?

**Update:**

I just realized that the problem is not directly related to export. When I increase the magnification of my notebook to, say, 300%, the same effect occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is another `Magnify` problem like [(138978)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/138978/121), as you observe.  I think the lesson from this, unhappy as it may be, is not to expect `ImageResolution` to work properly.  Instead craft your graphics (or other output) directly at the resolution that you want.

I mean something like this:

```
plot =
 Plot3D[100, {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, .4}
  , PlotRange -> {{0, 3}, {0, .4}, {0, 100}}
  , BoxRatios -> {3, .4, .5}
  , ViewPoint -> {0, -Pi, 1.3}
  , AxesStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[5]
  , BoxStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[5]
  , Mesh -> None
  , TicksStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 24]
  , ImageSize -> 3 {710, 220}
 ]

Export["test.png", plot];
```

It may be possible in some (many?) cases to still take advantage of automatic scaling using things like [`Thickness`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Thickness.html) in place of [`AbsoluteThickness`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AbsoluteThickness.html), and [`Scaled`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Scaled.html).  The use of a `Scaled` [`FontSize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FontSize.html) does not seem to be universal however so be prepared for problems of its own if you use this.  Exampe:

```
plot2 =
 Plot3D[100, {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, .4}
  , PlotRange -> {{0, 3}, {0, .4}, {0, 100}}
  , BoxRatios -> {3, .4, .5}
  , ViewPoint -> {0, -Pi, 1.3}
  , AxesStyle -> Thickness[0.002]
  , BoxStyle -> Thickness[0.002]
  , Mesh -> None
  , BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> Scaled[0.02]}
  , ImageSize -> {710, 220}
 ];
```

You can `Show` or `Export` this object at different `ImageSize` specifications and have it scale fairly accurately:

```
Show[plot2, ImageSize -> 400]
Show[plot2, ImageSize -> 1800]
```

[image]

Comment: I'm happy that there is at least a general workaround.

Comment: @Felix See my update; *maybe* it will be of use to you, or maybe it will cause its own problems and bring you back to exact specification as in my first example.

Comment: Thanks for this update. Personally, I will try to avoid magnification in this case, as you originally suggested. But I'm sure that there are use cases for the other approach.