# Combine Plots into a single non-rasterized Graphic with no spacing

Tags: plotting, graphics, grid-layouts

Suppose that I have two plots, `pl1` and `pl2`:

```
pl1 = Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 350]
pl2 = Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 350]
```

[image: pl1]

[image: pl2]

I would like to **(1) combine** these plots side-by-side in a **(2) non-rasterized** graphic with **(3) no spacing**.

I get pretty close to my desired result by using `Grid` with `Spacings -> 0`:

```
Grid[{{pl1, pl2}}, Spacings -> 0]
```

[image: grid]

The above satisfies my requirements **(2)** and **(3)**: the result is **non-rasterized**, and there is **no spacing** between the plots.  However, the above doesn't satisfy my requirement **(1)**, that the plots be **combined** into a *single* `Graphic` object.  That is, if I click on either of the plots, I see that they are separate `Graphic` objects:

[image: gridA]

[image: gridB]

So the above approach doesn't satisfy all of my requirements.  (Why do I need the plots to be combined in a single `Graphic`?  The reason is that I want to be able to place other `Graphic` objects -- e.g., text, arrows, shapes, etc. -- that *span* the two plots.)

Another possibility is to use `ImageAssemble`, but unfortunately this leads to a rasterized image:

```
ImageAssemble[{{pl1, pl2}}]
```

[image: imageassemble]

A third possibility is to use `GraphicsGrid` with `Spacings -> 0`:

```
GraphicsGrid[{{pl1, pl2}}, Spacings -> 0]
```

[image: graphicsgrid]

It seems that this produces a single `Graphic` object (**(1)**) that is not rasterized (**(2)**), but, unfortunately, there is spacing between the plots.

Do you have any suggestions?  Is there any way to remove the spacing/padding in `GraphicsGrid`?

Comment: @Jens Thanks.  I think my question is more general, though.  I just want to combine two `Graphics` objects side-by-side.  It's almost like I am looking for a way to flatten a `Grid` objects so that two `Graphics` objects in neighboring cells are combined into a single `Graphics` object.

Comment: Why do you need the result to be a single `Graphics` object?  What properties do single `Graphics` objects have that you need to rely on later?  This is a very important question.  You can combine them using `Inset`s, but I'm not sure you'll like the result, as it might not behave the way you expect when you resize it.

Comment: Nowadays I use SciDraw for figures with multiple panels: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/37880/12 But again, you can't resize a SciDraw figure directly.  You have to decide on the size when you make it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like the following:

```
pl1=Plot[x,{x,0,1},Frame->True,ImageSize->350, 
 ImagePadding->{{Scaled[0.05],None},{Automatic,Automatic}}];
pl2=Plot[x^2,{x,0,1},Frame->True,ImageSize->350, 
 ImagePadding-> {{None,Scaled[0.05]},{Automatic,Automatic}}];

GraphicsGrid[{{pl1,pl2}},Spacings->{Scaled[-0.07],0}]
```

[image]

This removes the padding from the graphics themselves with the option `ImagePadding`, and a magic number of -0.07...There is likely a better way.

Comment: Unfortunately, in this answer, the result is not a *single* `Graphic` object.  Sorry.

Comment: Yikes you are right...

Comment: changed to make result a Graphics