# Drawing a Gradient Between Two Circular Arcs

Tags: graphics

Suppose I wanted to use Mathematica graphics primitives to create a gradient of colors between two circular arcs. It's easy enough to make an area between two circles a solid color, but what if I wanted to have the area between two colors blur from black to white as you go out in radius?

VertexColor provides this kind of functionality for polygons, but I'm not sure how it would work for shapes containing circular arcs.

Comment: Not sure if the gradient itself is supposed to radial or linear. In any case, [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6562/245) seems to be related.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I just realized that the parametrization in my previous [revision](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/revisions/73975/2) of this answer is a special case of [bipolar coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipolar_coordinates). Every rectangle in bipolar coordinates $\theta_1<\theta<\theta_2,\ \tau_1<\tau<\tau_2$ is a region between four arcs. Two arcs is just a simple special case.

Here is my realization of bipolar coordinates with special stretching to make  texture more uniform and avoid shrinking at points $\tau=\pm\infty$. This parametrization have two additional parameters $(\theta_0,\tau_0)$. It is a reference point where texture is locally uniform.

```
bc[{τ1_, τ2_, τ0_: 1}, {θ1_, θ2_, θ0_: Scaled[0.5]}, opts___] := 
 Module[{u, v, t, q, t1, t2, q1, q2, μ, ν},
  μ = Abs@Tan[θ0/2] /. Scaled@x_ :> Rescale[x, {0, 1}, {θ1, θ2}] // Chop;
  ν = Abs@Tanh[τ0/2] /. Scaled@x_ :> Rescale[x, {0, 1}, {τ1, τ2}] // Chop;
  {t1, t2} = Which[μ == 0, #, Chop[1/μ] == 0, -1/#, True, ArcTan[# μ]] &@Tanh[{τ1, τ2}/2];
  {q1, q2} = If[ν == 0, Tan[#/2], ArcTan[ν+1 - Cos@#(ν-1), Sin@#(ν-1)] + #/2] & /@ {θ1, θ2};
  u = Which[μ == 0, t, Chop[1/μ] == 0, -1/t, True, Tan@t/μ];
  v = If[ν == 0, q, Tan@q/ν];
  First@Cases[#, _GraphicsComplex, ∞] &@
   ParametricPlot[{u (1 + v^2), (1 - u^2) v}/(1 + u^2 v^2), {t, t1, t2}, {q, q1, q2}, opts]]
```

You can use any option of the parametric plot

```
Graphics[bc[{0.5, 4}, {-π, π/2}, Mesh -> Full, PlotStyle -> {Opacity[1], 
    Texture@LinearGradientImage[{Red, Yellow, Blue}]}, BoundaryStyle -> Black]]
```

[image]

As mentioned above, two arcs is a special case

```
arcs[p1_, r1_, p2_, r2_, opts___] := 
 Module[{α = ArcTan @@ (p1 - p2), d = Norm[p2 - p1], a, τ1, τ2, d2},
  d2 = (d^2 + r1^2 - r2^2)/(2 d); a = Sqrt[d2^2 - r1^2];
  τ1 = Log[-(d2 + a)/r1]; τ2 = Log[(d2 + a - d)/r2];
  GeometricTransformation[#2, {Abs@a {{Cos@α, -Sin@α}, {Sin@α, 
         Cos@α}}, #}] &[p2 - {Cos@α, Sin@α} a Coth[τ2], 
   If[Im@a == 0, bc[{τ1, τ2}, {0, 2 π, π/2}, opts], α += π/2; 
    bc[{-∞, ∞}, {Im@τ1, Im@τ2}, opts]]]
  ]

p1 = {0.6, 0.2};
p2 = {0.9, 0.6};
r1 = 0.5;
r2 = 0.7;
Graphics[arcs[p1, -r1, p2, r2, PlotStyle -> {Opacity[1], 
    Texture@LinearGradientImage[{Top, Bottom} -> {Red, Yellow, 
        Blue}]}, BoundaryStyle -> Black]]
```

[image]

The output region (intersection, complement or union) depends on signs of radii

```
Graphics[arcs[p1, r1, p2, r2, PlotStyle -> {Opacity[1], 
    Texture@LinearGradientImage[{Top, Bottom} -> {Red, Yellow, 
        Blue}]}, BoundaryStyle -> Black]]
```

[image]

In the current realization the intersection of initial circles is not necessary

```
p1 = {2.5, 0.2};
p2 = {0.9, 0.6};
r1 = -3.5;
r2 = 0.7;
Graphics[{arcs[p1, r1, p2, r2, PlotStyle -> {Opacity[1], 
     Texture@LinearGradientImage[{Red, Yellow, Blue}]}, 
   BoundaryStyle -> Black]}]
```

[image]

You can do even open regions (here `RegionFunction` limits the region)

```
p1 = {0.5, 0.2};
p2 = {-1.1, 0.6};
r1 = -0.5;
r2 = -0.7;
Graphics[arcs[p1, r1, p2, r2, Mesh -> Full, PlotStyle -> {Opacity[1], 
    Texture@LinearGradientImage[{Red, Yellow, Blue}]}, 
  BoundaryStyle -> Black, RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, x^2 + y^2 < 200], 
  MaxRecursion -> 3], PlotRange -> 4]
```

[image]

Comment: I was asking how to make the last figure you generated.

Answer (score 8):

It is not possible to do this *directly* circular arcs.  `VertexColor` works for triangles (any other polygon will be broken up into triangles before the colours are applied).  If you need a gradient fill for an arbitrary shape, it needs to be approximated using a set of triangles first, then each triangle coloured individually.  There are several ways to do this, for example:

```
DensityPlot[x, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, (x - .5)^2 + y^2 < 1 && (x + .5)^2 + y^2 < 1]]
```

Add the `Mesh -> All` option to actually see the triangles it generates:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 7):

### With a little help from `LaminaData`

`LaminaData` is a good place to start. 
This leads to two approaches, each of which ultimately displays the figure in `RegionPlot`.

Approach 1 is based on graphics objects (the intersection region of two disks). The graphics object then employs `BoundaryDiscretizeRegion` or  `DiscretizeRegion`, the former being more efficient for not tracking points within the region.

Approach 2 uses a formula associated with an `ImplicitRegion`.  This turns out to be very similar to Szabolcs' approach.  I didn't generate the formula on my own but obtained it directly from `LaminaData[]`.

---

I wasn't sure how to draw the figure so I searched around in `LaminaData[]` and stumbled across the symmetric lens).  Here are it's diagram and image.  The `Diagram` revealed that it was the intersection of two disks.

```
LaminaData[Entity["Lamina", "LensSymmetric"], #] & /@ {"Name", "Diagram", "Image"}
```

[image: diagram1]

---

The `Region` property described the region as the intersection of two disks.
The `ImplicitRegion` property gave a formula.   These give rise to two different approaches, described below.

```
LaminaData[Entity["Lamina", "LensSymmetric"], "Region"]
LaminaData[Entity["Lamina", "LensSymmetric"], "ImplicitRegion"]
```

[image: diagram 2]

---

### 1. The Graphics Object (Disk) route

```
r = RegionIntersection[Disk[{0, 0}, 2], Disk[{3, 0}, 2]];
dr = DiscretizeRegion[r];
bdr = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[r];
RegionPlot[#, ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow", AspectRatio -> Full] & /@ {dr, bdr}
```

[image: regionplot]

---

### 2. The Formula Route

It was a straightforward matter to insert parameters into the formula.  Formal d and formal a were set to 1.  They can be tweaked as desired.  Formal x and formal y were replaced with `x`, `y`.
The color function was then applied.

```
d = 1; a = 1;
r = ImplicitRegion[y^2 + (x - d/2)^2 <= a^2 && y^2 + (x + d/2)^2 <= a^2, {x, y}];
RegionPlot[r, ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow", AspectRatio -> Full]
```

[image: full aspect ratio]

Answer (score 6):

Not sure if I understand your question correctly, but here is my approach:

```
With[{r = 1}, 
 RegionPlot[
  x^2 + y^2 < r^2 && x^2 + (y + r)^2 > 2 r^2, {x, -1, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
  MaxRecursion -> 5, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
  ColorFunction -> (Blend[{White, Black}, #] &)]]
```

[image]

Or using [ColorFunction](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorFunction.html) and [ColorData](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorData.html):

```
With[{r = 1}, 
 RegionPlot[
  x^2 + y^2 < r^2 && x^2 + (y + r)^2 > 2 r^2, {x, -1, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
  MaxRecursion -> 5, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
  ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, ColorData["GrayTones"][y .99]], 
  BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick]]]
```

[image]

The available Gradients you can find with the command `ColorData["Gradients"]`:

> {AlpineColors,Aquamarine,ArmyColors,AtlanticColors,AuroraColors,AvocadoColors,BeachColors,BlueGreenYellow,BrassTones,BrightBands,BrownCyanTones,CandyColors,CherryTones,CMYKColors,CoffeeTones,DarkBands,DarkRainbow,DarkTerrain,DeepSeaColors,FallColors,FruitPunchColors,FuchsiaTones,GrayTones,GrayYellowTones,GreenBrownTerrain,GreenPinkTones,IslandColors,LakeColors,LightTemperatureMap,LightTerrain,MintColors,NeonColors,Pastel,PearlColors,PigeonTones,PlumColors,Rainbow,RedBlueTones,RedGreenSplit,RoseColors,RustTones,SandyTerrain,SiennaTones,SolarColors,SouthwestColors,StarryNightColors,SunsetColors,TemperatureMap,ThermometerColors,ValentineTones,WatermelonColors}

You can also "steer" the gradient:

```
With[{r = 1}, 
 RegionPlot[
  x^2 + y^2 < r^2 && x^2 + (y + r)^2 > 2 r^2, {x, -1, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
  MaxRecursion -> 5, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
  ColorFunction -> 
   Function[{x, y}, ColorData["GrayTones"][y Sqrt[2]]], 
  BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Blue, Thick]]]
```

[image]