# Rounded rectangle with color gradient

Tags: graphics

Basically I'd like to produce a graphic like this:

[image: rectangle]

That is a rectangle with rounded corners, filled with a color gradient. While `Rectangle` offers the `RoundingRadius` option that takes care of the round corners, there is no obvious way of getting the color gradient to work. Using `Polygon` it's easy to [implement the gradient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8142179/), but I can only think of *very* messy ways of rounding the corners. Can I have both?

### Update

I just found [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6562/). That's very close to what I want, but that solution doesn't allow for nice edges.

Comment: First ideas: You can use Texture or you can write a formula for a rounded rectangle and use RegionFunction with DensityPlot.

Comment: Define "nice edges."  `EdgeForm[Thickness[0.02]]`?

Comment: you can try `EdgeForm`

Comment: This question *is* a duplicate.  You can just use e.g. `BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Red, Thickness[0.01]]` in the Accepted solution to get what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may be messy indeed, but it gets us scalable vector graphics:

```
w = 10;
r = 1.2;
h = 3.5;
dt = π/40;
pts =
  {
   {0, 0}, {w, 0},
   Sequence@@Table[{w, 0} + r { Sin[t], 1 - Cos[t]}, {t, dt, π/2 - dt, dt}],
   {w + r, r}, {w + r, h},
   Sequence@@Table[{w, h} + r { Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, dt, π/2 - dt, dt}],
   {w, h + r}, {0, h + r},
   Sequence@@Table[{0, h} + r { -Sin[t], Cos[t]}, {t, dt, π/2 - dt, dt}],
   {-r, h}, {-r, r},
   Sequence@@Table[{0, r} - r { Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, dt, π/2 - dt, dt}]
  };

Graphics[
  {
    EdgeForm[{Black, Thickness[0.02]}], 
    Polygon[pts, VertexColors -> (Blend[{White, Red}, #[[2]]/(h + r)] & /@ pts)]
  }
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

Using a tweaked version of my answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7657/862) and a graphics expression which draws the rectangle outline separately:

```
texturedShape[img_, shape_] := 
 Module[{g, p, ar, i}, g = Graphics[shape, PlotRangePadding -> 0];
  p = Polygon[AbsoluteOptions[g, PlotRange][[1, 2]] /.
    {{l_, r_}, {b_, t_}} :> {{l, b}, {l, t}, {r, t}, {r, b}},
    VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 0}}];
  ar = AbsoluteOptions[g, AspectRatio][[1, 2]];
  i = SetAlphaChannel[img, ColorNegate@Rasterize[g, ImageSize -> ImageDimensions@img]];
  {Texture[ImageData@i], p}]

With[{
  rect = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {2, 1}, RoundingRadius -> 0.2],
  tex = LinearGradientImage[{Top, Bottom} -> {Red, White}, {200, 100}]},
 Graphics[{
   (* inside  *) texturedShape[tex, rect],
   (* outline *) FaceForm[None], EdgeForm[{Thickness[0.02], Black}], rect}]]
```

[image]