# How to create custom Graphics primitive?

Tags: graphics, function-construction, syntax

How to create custom `Graphics primitive`?

It should have the following properties, resembling properties of built-in geometric figures, like `Circle` etc:

1. Has constant head, say `RoundedRectangle`. It should not evaluate to the list of lines, so as normal `Rectangle`.
2. Can serve as a subject for `GeometricTransformation`

Comment: `Rectangle` is a function turning some parameters into a graphics object. Such a function for rounded rectangles can be found in this post: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1882/rectangle-with-rounded-edges

Comment: Suzan, I don't understand what you are looking for in this question. Can you be a bit more explicit about what you are looking for?

Comment: Are you asking how to define an object that _Mathematica_ will treat as a graphic primitive such as `Disk` or `Circle`?

Comment: @m_goldberg, yes it can be said this way

Comment: @Anon thanks! didn't knew about this parameter for rectangle; but the general question persists

Comment: So if your geometric object (let's call it `myShape`) was defined so that `myShape[]` was a valid form (as it is for `Circle`, you would expect evaluating `Graphics[myShape[]]` to draw it, and not produce the message: "myShape is not a Graphics primitive or directive."?

Comment: You might want to look into the old packages ``Graphics`Arrow` `` or ``Graphics`Spline` `` to see how they implemented primitives that were once not built-in.

Comment: @0x4A4D how to see the code? :)

Comment: Well, look for the packages in your *Mathematica* installation...

Comment: It seems that you are under a common misconception. As far as the kernel is concerned, `Graphics` is inert, i.e. it has _no_ `DownValues`. It is only in the formatting end of things that it is turned into an image. The same applies to the primitives, like `Rectangle`, but they are only formatted when found within a `Graphics(3D)` object. So, `Rectangle` remains a `Rectangle` and `GeometricTransformation` can be applied to it.

Answer (score 28):

Try this:

```
SetAttributes[createPrimitive, HoldAll]

createPrimitive[patt_, expr_] := 
 Typeset`MakeBoxes[p : patt, fmt_, Graphics] := 
  Typeset`MakeBoxes[Interpretation[expr, p], fmt, Graphics]
```

Example:

```
createPrimitive[face[x_: 0.1],
 {Circle[{0, 0}, 1], Circle[{-0.3, 0.5}, x],
  Circle[{0.3, 0.5}, x], Line[{{-0.4, -0.2}, {0.4, -0.2}}]}]
```

It works as expected in `Graphics`:

```
g = Graphics[face[]]
```

[image]

`face` has no `DownValues` so it remains as `face` in `InputForm`:

```
InputForm[g]
(*  Graphics[face[]]  *)
```

[image]

```
(*  Graphics[face[], ImageSize -> {63., Automatic}]  *)
```

It works with `GeometricTransformation`:

```
Graphics[GeometricTransformation[face[0.2], ShearingTransform[Pi/4, {1, 0}, {0, 1}]]]
```

[image]

**A note about colours**

A commenter asked *"How would you rewrite this function to color the different components differently?"*  The answer is that colours can be used in the definition of the custom primitive just as in any other graphics expression, but note that the expression that goes into `` Typeset`MakeBoxes `` must be something that the Front End understands, e.g. `RGBColor[1,0,0]` rather than `Red`. If you want to use named colours like `Red` you will need to let the kernel evaluate the expression to convert them to `RGBColor` directives.

So for example you could:

Manually specify the colours as `RGBColor` directives:

```
createPrimitive[myprim[x_], {RGBColor[1, 0, 0], Circle[{0, 0}, x]}]
```

Use named colours and override the hold attribute with `Evaluate`:

```
createPrimitive[myprim[x_], Evaluate @ {Red, Circle[{0, 0}, x]}]
```

Or just remove the hold attribute completely:

```
ClearAttributes[createPrimitive, HoldAll];
createPrimitive[myprim[x_], {Red, Circle[{0, 0}, x]}]
```

In the last two cases you should guard against `x` already having a value, e.g. with `Block` or by using `\[FormalX]` instead of `x`

Comment: +1. What does ``Typeset`MakeBoxes`` do exactly? (lazy to start a spelunking battle)

Comment: @Rojo, I don't understand the details, but it's used internally by `MakeBoxes` to convert graphics primitives to boxes. I don't think it's possible to give definitions for creating graphics boxes directly with `MakeBoxes`, you have to use ``Typeset`MakeBoxes`` instead.

Comment: That's nice, thanks

Comment: I don't quite get the whole MakeBoxes yet, but it is beautiful.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see how to do what you are asking for without modifying the built-in definition of `Graphics`, something I would be extremely reluctant to do. In my own work, the closest I have come to meeting your requirements is to define functions that define shapes by returning lists consisting of graphics directives and primitives. This has worked well enough to satisfy me so far.

Here is an example.

```
dashedPoly[pts : {{_, _} ..}, 
           fill : (_RGBColor | _GrayLevel | _Hue) : Transparent] :=
    {fill, EdgeForm[Dashing[Small]], Polygon[pts]}
```

And here are two examples of the function in use.

```
Module[{A, B, C},
  A = {0., 0.}; B = {0., 3.}; C = {4., 0.};
  Graphics[dashedPoly[{A, B, C}]]]
```

[image: triangle1.png]

```
With[{blue = ColorData["HTML", "DeepSkyBlue"]}, 
  Module[{A, B, C},
    A = {0., 0.}; B = {0., 3.}; C = {4., 0.};
    Graphics[dashedPoly[{A, B, C}, blue]]]]
```

[image: triangle2.png]