# Can I define new graphics directives?

Tags: graphics, customization

Is it possible to define new graphics directives?

For example, suppose I want to be able to use the following code:

```
Graphics[{ BigPointSize[0.07], SmallPointSize[0.04],
           Red, BigPoint[{1,1}], BigPoint[{1,3}], SmallPoint[{3,1}],
           Blue, SmallPoint[{2,2}], SmallPoint[{3,2}], BigPoint[{0,0}]
        }]
```

Is there any way to define `BigPointSize`, `SmallPointSize`, `BigPoint`, and `SmallPoint` so that this code will work as intended?  Ideally `BigPointSize` and `SmallPointSize` should have all of the functionality of other graphics directives, e.g. scoping inside of lists, and the ability to call the command multiple times within the same list.

(Obviously it's possible to draw these points in other ways, but I'm curious whether it's possible to get this *syntax* to work.)

**Edit:** Just to clarify, I would like `BigPointSize` and `SmallPointSize` to work the same way as PointSize and other graphics directives.  For example, the code

```
Graphics[{ BigPointSize[0.1],
           { BigPointSize[0.05], BigPoint[{0,0}] },
           BigPoint[{1,0}]
        }]
```

should produce one point of size `0.05` and one point of size `0.1`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Protect[BigPointSize, BigPoint, SmallPointSize, SmallPoint];

UserGraphics[gr_, opt : OptionsPattern[Graphics]] := Module[
  {
    BigPointSizeStack, BigPointSizeExec, BigPointExec,
    SmallPointSizeStack, SmallPointSizeExec, SmallPointExec,
    TempList, TempListExec,
  },

  BigPointSizeStack = {0.1};  (* default value *)
  BigPointSizeExec[s_] := (BigPointSizeStack[[-1]] = s; {});
  BigPointExec[p_] := {PointSize[BigPointSizeStack[[-1]]], Point[p]};

  SmallPointSizeStack = {0.1};(* default value *)
  SmallPointSizeExec[s_] := (SmallPointSizeStack[[-1]] = s; {});
  SmallPointExec[p_] := {PointSize[SmallPointSizeStack[[-1]]], Point[p]};

  TempListExec[x___] := Module[{retval},
    AppendTo[BigPointSizeStack, BigPointSizeStack[[-1]]];
    AppendTo[SmallPointSizeStack, SmallPointSizeStack[[-1]]];

    retval = {x} /. {
                      BigPointSize -> BigPointSizeExec,
                      SmallPointSize -> SmallPointSizeExec,
                      BigPoint -> BigPointExec,
                      SmallPoint -> SmallPointExec
                    };

   BigPointSizeStack = Delete[BigPointSizeStack, -1];
   BigPointSizeStack = Delete[SmallPointSizeStack, -1];
   retval
   ];

  Graphics[(gr //. x_List :> TempList @@ x) /. TempList :> TempListExec, opt]
]




gr = {Line[{{0, -1}, {6, 0}}], BigPoint[{1, 0}], BigPointSize[0.02], 
      BigPoint[{2, 0}], {BigPointSize[0.03], BigPoint[{3, 0}], Red, 
      BigPointSize[0.04], BigPoint[{4, 0}]}, BigPoint[{5, 0}]};



UserGraphics[gr, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{0, 6}, {-1, 1}}]
```

I don't belive, but I wrote it, and it works !!!

I tried to use obvious tricks and commands, which easily can be found in the documentation.
The function `UserGraphics` supports all options and properties of Graphics.
It also supports `BigPointSize`, `SmallPointSize` directives,
and `BigPoint`, `SmallPoint` primitives.

It is the first version, so all found bugs/questions/comments/remarks are welcome !

Comment: This looks almost right, but the code under "Edit" in my original question (but with UserGraphics instead of graphics) is producing two points of the same size.

Comment: No, they are not the same size.

Comment: Let us check. Please show me the output of the command `InputForm[UserGraphics[...]]`

Comment: Ok, I restarted the kernel and it's working for me now.  It must have been because I evaluated your previous code snippet and didn't ClearAll the symbols.  Thanks a lot for the answer!

Answer (score 5):

It is possible to use [`Style`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Style) options as "graphics directives", and [`CurrentValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CurrentValue) can be used to query the values of these options. For example, suppose we use [`AutoIndent`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AutoIndent) as the graphics directive:

```
Graphics[
    {
    AutoIndent -> .1, {PointSize[Dynamic@CurrentValue@AutoIndent], Point[{0,0}]}, 
    {AutoIndent -> .2, {PointSize[Dynamic@CurrentValue@AutoIndent], Point[{1,1}]}},
    {PointSize[Dynamic@CurrentValue@AutoIndent], Point[{1,0}]}
    },
    ImageSize->200,
    PlotRange->{{-1,2},{-1,2}},
    Axes->True
]
```

[image]

Notice how the point at {1, 0} uses the initial [`AutoIndent`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AutoIndent) value. It is also possible to use `` Typeset`MakeBoxes `` so that `BigPointSize` and `BigPoint` only evaluate when the [`Graphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics) expression is converted to boxes, as pointed out by Simon Woods in his [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/27209/45431) to [How to create custom [`Graphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics) primitive?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/27184/45431). I will use a couple [`AutoStyleOptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AutoStyleOptions) settings as my "graphics directives":

```
Typeset`MakeBoxes[BigPointSize[rhs_], StandardForm, Graphics] := Typeset`Hold[
    "AutoStyleOptionsHighlightGlobalToLocalScopeConflicts"->rhs
]
Typeset`MakeBoxes[SmallPointSize[rhs_], StandardForm, Graphics] := Typeset`Hold[
    "AutoStyleOptionsHighlightMissingArgumentsWithTemplate"->rhs
]
Typeset`MakeBoxes[BigPoint[a_], StandardForm, Graphics] := {
    PointSize -> Dynamic @ Replace[
        CurrentValue["AutoStyleOptionsHighlightGlobalToLocalScopeConflicts"],
        Except[_?NumberQ]->.1
    ],
    PointBox[a]
}
Typeset`MakeBoxes[SmallPoint[a_], StandardForm, Graphics] := {
    PointSize -> Dynamic @ Replace[
        CurrentValue["AutoStyleOptionsHighlightMissingArgumentsWithTemplate"],
        Except[_?NumberQ]->.03
    ],
    PointBox[a]
}
```

And here's an example:

```
Graphics[
    {
    Line[{{0,-1},{6,0}}],
    BigPoint[{1,0}], Red, SmallPoint[{1,.5}],
    BigPointSize[0.02], SmallPointSize[.01],
    BigPoint[{2,0}], Blue, SmallPoint[{2, .5}],
    {
        BigPointSize[0.03], SmallPointSize[.04], BigPoint[{3,0}],
        Green, BigPointSize[0.04], BigPoint[{4,0}], SmallPoint[{4, .5}]
    },
    BigPoint[{5,0}], SmallPoint[{5, .5}]
    },
    Frame->True,
    PlotRange->{{0,6},{-1,1}}
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
BigPointSizeValue = 1;

BigPointSize[s_] := (BigPointSizeValue = s;)

BigPoint[p_] := {PointSize[BigPointSizeValue], Point[p]}

SmallPointSizeValue = 1;

SmallPointSize[s_]:=(SmallPointSizeValue = s;)

SmallPoint[p_] := {PointSize[SmallPointSizeValue], Point[p]}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  This works for the given code snippet, but it doesn't have the other properties of graphics directives, such as scoping within lists.

Comment: No problem, just declare them like this: `BigPoint[p_] := Sequence[PointSize[BigPointSizeValue], Point[p]]`

Comment: Thanks.  The Sequence trick improves things, but still doesn't replicate the functionality I would like.  See the edit to my question.

Comment: I think without a "preprocessor" function it is impossible to inform to a given `BigPointSize[...]` at what level of the list it is called. If there is no built-in method to add Directives, we should use `Graphics` with preprocessiong function in this form `Graphics[proc[gr]]`.

Comment: Do you like the idea of preprocessor? If yes, I can write a draft version of the code.

Comment: It sounds like a preprocessor would work well, especially if it is possible to redefine the Graphics command to include the preprocessing.  If it's not too much trouble, I'd love to see some possible code.