# Point-like function but with diamond instead of circle

Tags: graphics

I would like to use something like `Point[x,y]` to plot diamonds instead of small circles ("points"). I'm creating charts from scratch inside a `Graphics` expression using my own graphics functions. I've looked through the documentation and questions here and haven't found anything about how to do it.

Comment: Have you looked at [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/27184/3066)?

Comment: I've seen your icon, but it hadn't registered as an example of what I wanted to do. Did you use translate?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by "your icon". I gave a link to a previous posted question that I think relevant to yours.

Comment: @m_goldberg I believe he meant your SE avatar which is automatically generated. It has some rhombi in its corners.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use `Translate` for this purpose, which can not only translate along a single vector, but can create multiple copies translated along different vectors.

For example, let's use these (relative) positions:

```
points = RandomReal[10, {10, 2}]
```

Then

```
Graphics[
 Translate[Triangle[], points]
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Just make sure that your source object is centred around `{0,0}`, otherwise the plot will be misaligned, like here:

```
Graphics[
 {Translate[Triangle[], points],
  Red, PointSize[Large], Point[points]}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I was just lazy to make a proper diamond so I use `Triangle` ...

Comment: `Graphics[Translate[Rotate[Rectangle[], 45 Degree], points]]` for diamonds?

Comment: @kguler That is not centred on `{0,0}`, so we get back to me being lazy to make a proper diamond ;-)

Comment: @Szabolcs Yet another function I didn't know about. Translate seems pretty handy. It seems like it should work.

Comment: @Szabolcs It works! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I would define a function `diamond` that draws diamonds centered at given point and with a specified bounding box.

```
diamond[xy : {x_, y_} : {0, 0}, wh : {w_, h_} : {1, 1}] := 
 Translate[Polygon[{{w/2., 0.}, {0., h/2.}, {-w/2., 0}, {0., -h/2.}}], xy]
Graphics[
  Table[{Hue[RandomReal[]], diamond[RandomReal[1, {2}], RandomReal[.2, {2}]]}, {200}]]
```

[image: diamonds]

Comment: How does the syntax [xy : {x_, y_} : {0, 0} work?  Is it like a chain of defaults?

Comment: @GeorgeWolfe. It does look like a chain of defaults, but it isn't. The full-form of the first argument to `diamond` is `Optional[Pattern[xy, List[Pattern[x, Blank[]], Pattern[y, Blank[]]]], List[0, 0]]`, so it can be read `(<pattern-name> : <pattern>) : <default>`. Colon ( : ) is one of few operators in _Mathematica_ that is interpreted differently according to context. The first colon is interpreted as the infix form of `Pattern` and the second as the infix form of `Optional`.

Answer (score 2):

here some examples how to define your own PlotMarkers

```
plotmarkers = 
 colors // 
  Map[Graphics[{#, Disk[]}, ImageSize -> 8] // 
      ToString[#, FormatType -> StandardForm] & // Function, #] &
ListPlot[{{1, 2, 3, 5, 8}, {2, 3, 6, 9, 10}, {4, 5, 7, 10, 12}}, 
 PlotMarkers -> plotmarkers, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotRangeClipping -> False]

plotmarkers = {Style["\[FilledDiamond]", 16, Lighter@Red], 
  Style["\[FilledDiamond]", 16, Lighter@Blue], 
  Style["\[FilledDiamond]", 16, Lighter@Green]}
ListPlot[{{1, 2, 3, 5, 8}, {2, 3, 6, 9, 10}, {4, 5, 7, 10, 12}}, 
 PlotMarkers -> plotmarkers, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotRangeClipping -> False]
```

You may use Inset or Text to place them accordingly in Graphics, or if available the Option PlotMarkers -> yourPlotmarkers

[image: PlotMarkers]

```
plotmarkers = {Style["\[FilledDiamond]", 16, Lighter@Red], 
  Style["\[FilledDiamond]", 16, Lighter@Blue], 
  Style["\[FilledDiamond]", 16, Lighter@Green]}
point[x_, y_, which_] := Inset[plotmarkers[[which]], {x, y}]
Graphics[{point[1, 0, 1], point[-1, 0, 1], point[0, 1, 2], 
  point[0, -1, 2], point[0, 0, 3]}]
```

[image: diamond2]

Comment: +1 Pity that you don't show that the green diamond is at (0,0) :)