# How to combine one or more rotated graphics objects?

Tags: graphics, rotation

I wish to produce an image with more than one composite graphics objects which have been modified using *Rotate*. I feel this should not be difficult, but haven't yet found a solution.

A simple example using only *Disk* illustrates the problem.

```
e1 = Rotate[Graphics[Disk[{0, 0}, {1/3, 1/4}]], \[Pi]/3];
e2 = Rotate[Graphics[Disk[{0, 0}, {1/3, 1/4}]], \[Pi]/7];
```

The following attempt fails:

```
Show[e1,e2]
```

> > Show::gcomb: Could not combine the graphics objects in Show[]

How should this best be achieved ?

Comment: I think this is a reasonable question and ought not be closed.

Comment: Perhaps you can also make use of this: [How to create custom Graphics primitive?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/27184/245)

Comment: Would'nt be easier to just change the order of Graphics and Rotate? Like this: `e1 = Graphics[Rotate[{Blue, Opacity[.75], Disk[{0, 0}, {1/3, 1/4}]}, \[Pi]/3]];
e2 = Graphics[Rotate[{Red, Opacity[.75], Disk[{0, 0}, {1/3, 1/4}]}, \[Pi]/7]];
Show[{e1, e2}]` ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/JFlkU.png)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The trick is just to get rid of the internal `Graphics` heads and then wrap the full expression in `Graphics`:

```
{e1, e2} /. Graphics -> Identity // Graphics
```

[image]

Comment: A very simple and surprising trick. Of course +1.

Comment: Hopefully master @kguler is proud of his padawan's use of `Identity` :)

Comment: @mfvonh, nice... +1 of course :)

Comment: this works when `Graphics` has a single argument (e.g. no graphics options in `e1` and `e2`). Otherwise, if, say `e2` has the option `ImageSize->300`, we need something less clean -- like `{e1, e2} /. 
  Rotate[Graphics[x_, y_], r_] :> Graphics[Rotate[x, r], y] // Show`

Comment: @kguler I think that should be `y___`, otherwise that seems like the best solution yet.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, good point, thank you. Also `r_` should be `r__`.

Answer (score 9):

**Update**

As noted in the comments by @pickett, the function `showF` in the original post does not preserve the relative positions of the inset graphics. I am not sure if it is possible to fix `showF` to address this issue. So, instead, I suggest an alternative approach using

```
show2F := Show[# /. Rotate[Graphics[x_, y___], r__] :> Graphics[Rotate[x, r], y],
              PlotRange -> All, ImagePadding -> Scaled[.025]] &

show2F@{e1, e2, e3}
```

[image]

---

**Original post**

An alternative approach similar to @mfvonh's replacement trick: Wrap inner graphics with `Inset` and the whole thing with `Graphics`

```
showF := Graphics[# /. Graphics -> Composition[Inset, Graphics]] &
```

or using the new Version10 syntax (thanks: @rojo)

```
Graphics@*ReplaceAll[Graphics->Inset@*Graphics]
```

Examples:

```
g1 = Graphics[{Red, Disk[{0, 0}, {1/3, 1/4}]}, ImageSize -> 250];
g2 = Graphics[{Blue, Opacity[.5], Disk[{0, 0}, {1/3, 1/4}]}, ImageSize -> 200];
g3 = Graphics[{Thickness[.03], Line[{{0, -1/2}, {0, 1}}], 
             {Blue, Line[{{0, -1/2}, {1, 1}}]}, 
             First@Plot[x Sin[6 x + 4], {x, -1, 1}, Axes -> False, 
                       PlotStyle -> {Thickness[.02], Orange}]}, ImageSize -> 250];
Row[{g1, g2, g3}]
```

[image]

```
e1 = Rotate[g1, Pi / 3];
e2 = Rotate[g2, Pi / 7];
e3 = Rotate[g3, Pi / 2];
Row[{e1, e2, e3}]
```

[image]

```
showF @ {e1, e2, e3}
```

[image]

Comment: My first upvote "just for laughs" - a brilliant late coup :)

Comment: ... and @mfvonh for the key idea.

Comment: No cows this time? ;)

Comment: @rm-rf, Inset and cows don't mix in v9 -- yet another reason to upgrade to V10 :)

Comment: +1. Similarly, `Graphics@*ReplaceAll[Graphics->Inset@*Graphics]`

Answer (score 7):

mfvonh's trick is nice, but I think it should be said that the normal approach is to rotate graphics primitives inside the `Graphics` wrapper.

```
Graphics[{
  Rotate[Disk[{0, 0}, {1/3, 1/4}], π/3], 
  Rotate[Disk[{0, 0}, {1/3, 1/4}], π/7]},
  ImageSize -> Small]
```

[image: graphics]

Comment: Isn't that what mfvonn does when he changes `Graphics` to `Identity`?

Comment: @Rojo. Yes, but it's rather the long way around the barn (as we say in the US), don't you think. This post is to make sure beginners see the way it normally done when they read this questions and its answers.

Answer (score 6):

As with some of the other approaches, the following does not maintain relative positions.

```
e1 = Rotate[Graphics[{Blue, Opacity[.75],
     Disk[{0, 0}, {1/3, 1/4}]}], \[Pi]/3];
e2 = Rotate[Graphics[{Red, Opacity[.75],
     Disk[{0, 0}, {1/3, 1/4}]}], \[Pi]/7];

Show[
 Rasterize[#, Background -> None] & /@
  {e1, e2}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Yet another method is to use [`Overlay`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Overlay.html).  Borrowing Bob Hanlon's example:

```
e1 = Rotate[Graphics[{Blue, Opacity[.75],
     Disk[{0, 0}, {1/3, 1/4}]}], π/3];
e2 = Rotate[Graphics[{Red, Opacity[.75],
     Disk[{0, 0}, {1/3, 1/4}]}], π/7];

Overlay[{e1, e2}]
```

[image]

Comment: With the caveat, as was noted in the comments to my deleted answer that at once point included `Overlay`, that the objects lose their relative positions.

Comment: @Pickett True, but kguler's `Inset` solution has the same problem as currently written.  I still think this is useful.