# Rotate imported images which are inset into a Graphics container and then overlapped?

Tags: graphics, image-processing

The methods given as answers to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/57803/how-to-combine-one-or-more-rotated-graphics-objects) do not seem to work here. I suspect it is because of my use of `Inset` function.

Consider two .png images [hand1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xezph.png) and [hand2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rq5RO.png), which can be overlapped to display an arm that can bend at the elbow. Up until now I was displaying the two pictures and moving them around dynamically by changing the display coordinates. The code is the following:

```
img1 = Import["...\\hand1.png"];
img2 = Import["...\\hand2.png"];
Gimg1[x_, y_] := Gimg1[x, y] = Graphics[Inset[img1, {0, 0}, {200 + x, 141.5 + y}, 400], PlotRange -> {{-200, 200}, {-141.5, 141.5}}, ImageSize -> 400];
Gimg2[x_, y_] := Gimg2[x, y] = Graphics[Inset[img2, {0, 0}, {200 + x, 141.5 + y}, 400], PlotRange -> {{-200, 200}, {-141.5, 141.5}}, ImageSize -> 400];
Dynamic[Show[{Gimg1[x1, y1], Gimg2[x2, y2]}]]
x1 = 0; y1 = 0; x2 = 0; y2 = 0;
```

where instead of `...` I put the proper path to the files. Now, if I change `x1,y1,x2,y2` I see the pictures moving around dynamically. To rotate the images, I figured that I would have to wrap them with `Rotate[...,θ, {218+x, 222+y}]`, where `{218, 222}` are the x-y-coordinates where the elbow appears in the untranslated picture. Therefore, I modify my code as:

```
img1 = Import["...\\hand1.png"];
img2 = Import["...\\hand2.png"];
Gimg1[x_, y_, θ_] := Gimg1[x, y, θ] = Rotate[ Graphics[Inset[img1, {0, 0}, {200 + x, 141.5 + y}, 400], PlotRange -> {{-200, 200}, {-141.5, 141.5}}, ImageSize -> 400],θ, {218+x, 222+y}];
Gimg2[x_, y_, θ_] := Gimg2[x, y, θ] = Rotate[ Graphics[Inset[img2, {0, 0}, {200 + x, 141.5 + y}, 400], PlotRange -> {{-200, 200}, {-141.5, 141.5}}, ImageSize -> 400],θ, {218+x, 222+y}];
Dynamic[Show[{Gimg1[x1, y1, θ1], Gimg2[x2, y2, θ2]}]]
x1 = 0; y1 = 0; x2 = 0; y2 = 0; θ1 = 0; θ2 = 0;
```

But now, unfortunately, the images do not even appear when using the `Show` command. I tried moving the wrapper `Rotate[...,θ, {218+x, 222+y}]` to lower levels, wrapping around the `Inset`, or even the images themselves. Nothing seems to work here. The question is, how can I rotate overlapped `Inset` images around a certain pixel coordinate while maintaining the ability to also translate the pictures and display everything dynamically and keeping it in a frame of fixed size?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the Documentation page for `Show`,

> `Show` can be used with `Graphics` and `Graphics3D`.

So you cannot combine objects with `Head` `Rotate` using `Show`.

When you move `Rotate` deeper and wrap it around `Image`, you obtain an error message saying that `Rotate` expects a `Graphics` primitive or directive while `Image` is not a `Graphics` primitive. A `Graphics` primitive which corresponds to `Image` is `Raster`, so you should convert it via `Show[img1][[1]]`. You could also use `Translate` instead of `Inset` for positioning the rotated image:

```
Graphics[{Translate[Rotate[Show[img1][[1]], Pi], {-.5, -.5}]}, Frame -> True]
```

> [image: graph]

If you wish to rotate in the linear RGB colorspace, you can perform it in the following way (I use functions `‌​sRGB2Linear` and `linear2sRGB` from [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/15992/280) answer):

```
linearRotate[sRGBimg_Image, \[Theta]_, size_: Automatic] := 
  linear2sRGB[ImageRotate[‌​sRGB2Linear[sRGBimg], \[Theta], size]];

Graphics[{Translate[Show[linearRotate[img1, Pi/3]][[1]], {-5, -5}], 
  Translate[Show[linearRotate[img2, Pi/3]][[1]], {-5, -5}]}, Frame -> True]
```

> [image: graph]

By default `ImageRotate` uses `Automatic` `Resampling` method which interpolates the pixel values using "the most suitable method". You can specify the resampling method explicitly (please try it in a Notebook for comparison with the default method, images posted here do not represent the actual output exactly):

```
linearRotate[sRGBimg_Image, \[Theta]_, size_: Automatic] := 
  linear2sRGB[
   ImageRotate[sRGB2Linear[sRGBimg], \[Theta], size, Resampling -> "Constant"]];

Graphics[{Translate[Show[linearRotate[img1, Pi/3]][[1]], {-5, -5}], 
  Translate[Show[linearRotate[img2, Pi/3]][[1]], {-5, -5}]}, Frame -> True]
```

> [image: graph]

Comment: This is very helpful! My only concern is now the color artifact that appears at the edges of the images due to rotation being done in the non-linear color format (what your other post from 2012 is about, where we talked earlier). As mentioned there, the linearized functions seem to misbehave for the above png's (at least when I try it). Any Idea how to fix it?

Comment: Oh, if I zoom in on the picture rotated in the linear RGB color space, it still seems that there are some color artifacts left at the edges (rims of slightly lighter orange appear). I wonder, is this something generic that cannot be fixed by applying linear RGB color space transformations?

Comment: The artifacts are due to `Resampling` method used by `ImageRotate`, of course performing rotation in the linear colorspace does not change the `Resampling` method. You can specify the method explicitly, see updated answer.

Comment: Oh, that is great to learn! It seems the `Resampling` option is present in `ImageRotate` but not the `Rotate` function. I prefer to use `Rotate` since it allows to rotate around a coordinate other than the center. For instance, if I want to leave the upper arm unrotated and only rotate the lower arm around the approximate coordinate of the elbow, it would look like the arm is bending in the elbow. I don't know how one would do this with `ImageRotate`. Is that possible?

Comment: Again, please read the Documentation! Under the "Properties & Relations" section on the page for `ImageRotate` you find direct answer to your question. Please check the Documentation before posing the questions here!