# Combining two 3D objects

Tags: graphics3d, rotation, geometric-transform

At this post
[How to combine one or more rotated graphics objects?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/57803/how-to-combine-one-or-more-rotated-graphics-objects)
There is a neat trick for combining 2D objects. When I apply it to 3D it does not work

This code of a pyramid on a cube to approximate a house is my first attempt

```
house3D = Graphics3D[{Pyramid[{{0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 
    1}, {.5, .5, 1.5}}], Cube[{.5, .5, .5}]} /. 
Graphics3D -> Identity // Graphics3D, Axes -> True]
```

I hope to end up with an object which will submit to RotationTransform in Manipulate somewhat like this

```
Manipulate[Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[None], GeometricTransformation[house3D, 
RotationTransform[k Pi/8, {1, 0, 0}]]}], {k, -1, 1}, SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

Comment: `First@house3D`

Comment: Perfect. Thanks

Comment: The replacement Graphics3D -> Identity has no effect: you're applying it to the list of graphics elements. Then //Graphics3D makes that list into a 3D graphics. So you get Graphics3D[Graphics3D[...], Axes->True] which doesn't display.

Comment: You'll get the same thing as First@house3D if you just create the 3D graphics directly: Graphics3D[{Pyramid[{{0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 
     1}, {.5, .5, 1.5}}], Cube[{.5, .5, .5}]}, Axes -> True]