# Precise cropping with ImageCrop

Tags: bugs, image-processing, opacity

**Bug introduced in 8 or earlier and persisting through 13.1.0**

<sub>Reported to the support as [CASE:3968587]. [Published](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1215584) on Wolfram Community.</sub>

---

In the presence of alpha channel `ImageCrop` doesn't remove borders at all despite the fact that the latter are *exactly* uniform (both in the color channels and in the alpha channel). Here is an example of inconsistent behavior of `ImageCrop` (checked with versions 8.0.4, 9.0.1, 11.2.0 and 11.3.0):

```
img = Rasterize[
   Graphics[{Circle[{0, 0}, 1], 
     Text[Style[l, FontFamily -> "Times"], {1.2, 0}]}, Frame -> False,
     PlotRange -> {{.9, 1.3}, All}], "Image", Background -> None];

Show[#, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> False, 
   PlotRangePadding -> None] & /@
 {img, ImageCrop[img], ImagePad[img, -BorderDimensions[img, 0]]}
```

> [image: screenshot]

The built-in `ImageCrop` function "effectively removes borders from *image* whose pixel value distribution is **almost uniform**" (emphasis mine). I need an efficient cropping function which removes borders whose pixel values are **identical**. What is the best way to do this in *Mathematica*? I don't need support for 3D images, but images with an alpha channel should be supported.

Comment: This is apparently the default in Version 7: "ImageCrop[image] effectively starts at the borders of image, then removes as many layers of pixels as possible where all their color values **exactly match** the colors of the borders." (emphasis mine)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Such hidden changes is a source of troubles for the users. On [the Documentation page of v.8](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v8/ref/ImageCrop.html) we read the same as [in v.9](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ImageCrop.html). But on the bottom of the page in v.8 nothing is said about changes since v.7 (one can see only "New in 7"). I think that the difference in the behavior [as compared to v.7](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v7/ref/ImageCrop.html) is significant. I wasted half an hour before realised that `ImageCrop` is "smarter" than I need!

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Usually when working with new version of *Mathematica* I check only the bottom of the page for the function I use and if nothing is said about changes I think that there are no significant changes. But this case is critical for me! I am forced to revrite some functions I thought reliable from version to version...

Comment: I agree.  That's a nasty change to not announce.  It would have been better to introduce a new Option for tolerance; this way old code would not break but users who wanted to could e.g. `SetOptions[ImageCrop, Tolerance -> 0.03]` and get the "new" behavior.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov +1 I think three small images (original, fuzzy and strict cropping) may improve the question comprehension time

Comment: @belisarius I have added an example (this case is opposite to what I got stuck on but it demonstrates inverse side of the problem). Obviously, new `ImageCrop` is a crap.

Comment: Nice, thanks a lot

Comment: I was experiencing this, in which images with alpha channel aren't actually cropped, but RGB images are though (both cases being "exactly uniform"). Not sure if something has changed in the new versions.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I just realized that [`BorderDimensions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BorderDimensions.html) accepts second argument as tolerance. So, what I need is

```
ImagePad[img, -BorderDimensions[img, 0]]
```

Comment: also available here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1252

Answer (score 2):

A workaround allowing `ImageCrop` to crop images having alpha channel is to temporarily set `ColorSpace -> Automatic`:

```
Image[ImageCrop[Image[img, ColorSpace -> Automatic]], ColorSpace -> "RGB"]
```

Also published here: http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1215584

---

Strongly related:

- [Blur, GaussianFilter and ImageConvolve doesn't work on some images](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/156210/280)