# Get Coordinates in Image Processing

Tags: image-processing

I'm new to Mathematica. I'm very impressed about it's abilities. It's very easy to achieve complex tasks. But I fail the simple ones.

**How can I get coordinates in image processing?**

I'd like to detect one of the following things

- absolute vertical center of the rectangle surrounding all white parts
- gravity center of all white parts

e.g.: for this picture

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GFCv.png]

I want to find the green point (center of outbound box).

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AcMp5.png]

Comment: So the center of outbound box (the green point in your example) is generally **NOT** the gravity center of all white parts, then which is the one you really want?

Comment: The question is more general: "How to find and handle positions/coordinates in images". I do not care, which aspect of the precise question is going to be answered ;-)

Comment: Then that will be a HUGE topic, with various methods for various problems. It's usually not the positions of points, but the special properties of those points, which distinguish them from points you want to drop, are essential for image processing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ImageValuePositions`, new in 9, can return a list of white pixel positions.

```
i = Import@"https://i.stack.imgur.com/opzqB.png";
p = ImageValuePositions[i, White] // Mean
(* {298.896, 21.3231} *)

HighlightImage[i, {p},
 Method -> {"CrossMarkers", 5}]
```

**Update: Surrounding rectangle**

Get the min/max of white pixel coordinates.

```
whites = ImageValuePositions[i, White];
corners = Transpose[{
   Through[{Min, Max}[First /@ whites]],
   Through[{Min, Max}[Last /@ whites]]}]
(* {{218.5, 0.5}, {373.5, 50.5}} *)
```

Make a rectangle boundary and highlight that region on the image.

```
rect = corners /. {{x1_, y1_}, {x2_, y2_}} :>
    With[{dx = 2}, Join[
      Table[{x1, y1} + {0, y}, {y, 0, y2 - y1, dx}],
      Table[{x1, y2} + {x, 0}, {x, 0, x2 - x1, dx}],
      Table[{x2, y2} - {0, y}, {y, 0, y2 - y1, dx}],
      Table[{x2, y1} - {x, 0}, {x, 0, x2 - x1, dx}]]];

HighlightImage[i, rect,
 Method -> {"DiskMarkers", 1}]
```

Comment: @Mr.Wizard But he *is* looking for "gravity center of all white parts."

Comment: @belisarius Okay, I've been put in my place. :-o (+1 to BoLe)

Comment: +1. Didn't notice the "gravity center" phrase in OP's question.

Answer (score 7):

Suppose your original image is `img`.

First we `Binarize` it:

```
imgBinarized = img // Binarize;
```

Then crop all the black boarders:

```
imgConcerned = ImageCrop[imgBinarized]
```

[image: imgConcerned]

So now, using the [`HitMissTransform`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/HitMissTransform.html) (also [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hit-or-miss_transform)), we can easily get its center position:

```
centerPos = HitMissTransform[imgBinarized, ImageData[imgConcerned]]
```

[image]

To achieve the appearance of your last picture, we construct a diamond marker first:

```
markerMatrix = Graphics[{EdgeForm[{White, Thick}], FaceForm[],
       Rotate[Rectangle[], π/4]},
      Background -> Black,
      ImageSize -> {15, 15}] // Rasterize //
    ColorConvert[#, "Grayscale"] & // ImageData;
```

Then convolve it with the `centerPos` image:

```
imgCenter = ImageConvolve[centerPos, markerMatrix];
```

Colorize it:

```
imgCenterColored = Image[
  # ImageData[imgCenter] & /@ {0, 3/4, 0, 1},
  "Real", ColorSpace -> "RGB", Interleaving -> False];
```

Compose it with the original image `img`:

```
ImageCompose[img, imgCenterColored]
```

[image]

You can explore the image processing functions in *Mathematica* and find yourself how to add the red boundary box.

## Edit

As cormullion suggested, in case you want the coordinate of the center point, you can extract it from the mask image `centerPos` straightway:

```
Position[Transpose[ImageData[centerPos, DataReversed -> True]], 1]
```

> {{297, 26}}

Comment: I like your `HitMissTransform`. If the OP wants the coordinates of the point, can they get that from `centerPos?`

Comment: @cormullion I think `ImageData` then using `Cases` or `ArrayRule` etc to extract it would be viable.

Comment: If he's new, he might want to see that...! (or `Position[Transpose[ImageData[centerPos, DataReversed -> True]], 1]` might work...)

Comment: @cormullion Thanks for suggestion. Have added it :)

Answer (score 7):

For another approach, there's always the `ComponentMeasurements` way:

```
cm = ComponentMeasurements[Dilation[i, BoxMatrix[5]] , "Centroid"]
```

> {1 -> {297.633, 23.7345}}

```
mean = Mean@cm[[All, 2]] (* not needed if only one component found*)

HighlightImage[i, 
 List@mean, 
 Method -> {"DiskMarkers", 3}, 
 HighlightColor -> Green]
```

[image: pic]

I'm not happy with the `Dilation` approach, though, which is a bit sloppy.

Comment: I thought of `Dilation` at first, but afraid it may change the center position given that the image pattern is not symmetric.

Comment: @Silvia I couldn't think of any dilation-towards-the-center commands. `MorphologicalTransform` doesn't do it either... :( I was close, anyway!

Comment: +1. Instead of `Dilation`, you can use the `ComponentMeasurements` overload that takes a label matrix instead of an image: `ComponentMeasurements[ImageData[Binarize[i]], "Centroid"]`. That way, you'll always get a single component, because the label matrix only contains 0 and 1.

Answer (score 5):

A variation of BoLe's center-of-gravity method for version 7:

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/opzqB.png"]

SparseArray[ImageData@Binarize@img]["NonzeroPositions"] // Mean // N
```

> ```
> {30.1769, 299.396}
> ```

Output in (y,x) order.

`SparseArray` is much faster than `Position`:

```
dat = ImageData@Binarize@img;

Do[SparseArray[dat]["NonzeroPositions"], {1500}] // Timing // First

Do[Position[dat, 1], {1500}] // Timing // First
```

> 0.14
>
> 2.465

Links to other uses of SparseArray Properties [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/23623/121).

Comment: Thank you for this very general answer! +1 for legacy support. Why is the resulting vector the wrong way arround: {y,x} instead of {x,y} ?

Comment: @Josua You're welcome.  It's just an artifact of the way array elements are indexed in *Mathematica*: row, then column.

Comment: @Josua By the way I just revised the timings to better emphasize the superiority of `SparseArray` over `Position`.

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way that exploits the fact that you have a constant black background. If your image is called `img`, then

```
small = ImageCrop[img]
```

crops it and leaves just the central rectangle.

[image]

Now you want the center of the cropped image, which can be found

```
cen = ImageDimensions[ImageCrop[img]]/2
```

To display the small image and the centerpoint:

```
Show[small, Graphics[{Thick, Orange, Point[{{cen, cen}}]}]]
```

This gives you a little orange dot at the center.

[image]

You can of course, change the orange dot to whatever you like.

Comment: +1. In this case `ImageCrop` works but in more complicated cases it can do wrong cropping: "[Precise cropping with ImageCrop](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20494/280)." The reliable way to crop is `ImagePad[img, -BorderDimensions[img, 0]]`.

Comment: Sure, that's why I prefaced my answer with "Here's one way that exploits the fact that you have a constant black background." In general you might want to binarize the image, and perhaps then apply some kind of erosion in order to make the background uniform. But in the present case the image was already binary and already noise-free.