# Find the coordinates of a hand drawn curve

Tags: graphics

Imagine I have saved a hand drawn curve as a jpg file. I want to be able to enclose it in a box and read off coordinates of the points that lie on the curve. One way is to click on a point and get the coordinates. But I want to automate this.

Comment: Related questions and answers have been posted at MSE. (For example, [23764](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23764)). Please, provide image(s) you want to work with.

Comment: How close is this WRI page, ["Get Coordinates from an Image"](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/GetCoordinatesFromAnImage.html), to what you want to do?

Comment: In this method I have to manually specify which points I am interested in. I want to feed a jpg image of a hand drawn curve and automatically get coordinates (end points mandatory, the number of points is an input)

Answer (score 10):

[image: img curve]

```
(* get the image *)
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFioq.png"]

(* get the pixel positions on the line *)
binz = Thinning@ColorNegate@Binarize@CurvatureFlowFilter[img, 2];
positions = PixelValuePositions[binz, 1];

(* create a graph structure connecting pixel positions in a chain *)
gr = SimpleGraph[
   NearestNeighborGraph[positions, 
    DistanceFunction -> ChessboardDistance, DirectedEdges -> False]];

(* make sure we discard any small pixels that are not on the main curve *)
largestgr = First@MaximalBy[ConnectedGraphComponents[gr], VertexCount];

(* the start/end pixels are the ones with lowest degree *)
{start, end} = 
  VertexList[largestgr][[
   Flatten@Position[VertexDegree[largestgr], 1]
  ]];

(* find path from start to end and plot *)
path = First[FindPath[largestgr, start, end]];
ListLinePlot[path, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image: curve plot]

---

This is a bit shorter if you use `DeleteSmallComponents` instead to remove any stray pixels not part of the curve:

```
bwimg = DeleteSmallComponents@Thinning@ColorNegate@Binarize@img;
gr = NearestNeighborGraph[PixelValuePositions[bwimg, 1], 
  DistanceFunction -> ChessboardDistance];
{start, end} = Select[VertexList@gr, VertexDegree[gr, #] == 1 &];
path = First@FindPath[gr, start, end];

HighlightImage[img, path]
ListLinePlot[path, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

---

If you need arbitrary paths that may contain loops and intersections, then maybe you should look at `FindCurvePath` instead:

```
img = Rasterize[Text["A"], RasterSize -> 64];
bwimg = DeleteSmallComponents@Thinning@ColorNegate@Binarize@img;
positions = PixelValuePositions[bwimg, 1];
paths = FindCurvePath[positions];
ListLinePlot[positions[[#]] & /@ paths]
```

[image]

Also, `ListCurvePathPlot[positions]` would work too.

Comment: Even thought I am not supposed to say "Thanks" I will. A huge thanks to flinty.

Comment: @QuasarSupernova Cheers! I will continue to elaborate on this answer if I find a shorter or more robust way to do it.

Comment: However it does not seem to work on the letter R and many others. I get this error : Set::shape: Lists {start,end} and {{244,184},{271,181},{250,113},{267,121},{270,109},{242,86},{282,137},{297,84},{294,83},{282,95}} are not the same shape.

Comment: Letters like R, X, A etc all have multiple endpoints, so there is no way to sort them (except maybe topologically) and therefore no way to list plot them as a single cuve. If you just need the points then `PixelValuePositions[#, 1]&@DeleteSmallComponents@Thinning@ColorNegate@Binarize@img` will work, and so will everything before the line `{start, end} ... ` - **You should provide examples of the curves you're working with and what you expect from them in your question**

Comment: Just points will do. I want to use this to parametrise the curve and to classify them topologically.

Comment: @QuasarSupernova Then you have everything you need  with this line: `positions = PixelValuePositions[binz, 1];` With the graph, you could use `FindCycle[gr, Infinity, All]` for the topology.

Comment: See this link. I am getting errors for anything more complicated than a line segment. 
 https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Hu9XA7ZPCJhnSix1nR-wr_DHpUgPiUbq/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Even the Star of David which has no end points does not work, gives same error as R,A e.t.c.

Comment: It's not a curve or a line. There is no 'start' or 'end' on the shape of the letter 'A' so I don't know why you expect a path to exist. You cannot `ListLinePlot` shapes like that in general unless you have an ordering to the graph vertices. At best you can just plot the points alone.

Comment: Even a triangle gives the same error.

Comment: I can easily order points on an triangle (or a circle)

Comment: @QuasarSupernova have a look at my edit. `FindCurvePath` might be better suited to your application than the graph method. Maybe consider adding examples of the curves you're interested in to your question as I told you in an earlier comment.