# How to align rotated images vertically

Tags: image-processing

I have recorded images of a calibration target which I use to determine the resolution of a camera. For that I measure the distance of the parallel bright bars by measuring the brightness variation along the center of the bars perpendicular to their long side. The thickness of the bars is given.

Usually I am not able to align the target exactly in vertical direction.

An example image is given here:

[image]

To turn the image into the vertical direction I used a code developed by Markus van Almsick.

Do you know another alternative solution for doing such an alignment automatically?

```
VerticalAlignment[img_Image] :=
 Module[
  {contours = ImageAdjust@GradientFilter[img, 1], 
   dims = ImageDimensions[img], lines, intersections, phis},
  lines = 
   Map[(# - dims/2) &, ImageLines[contours, MaxFeatures -> 12], {-2}];
  intersections = Apply[
    Replace[
      RegionIntersection[InfiniteLine[#1], InfiniteLine[#2]], 
      {Point[vec : {_, _}] :> ToPolarCoordinates[vec],
       EmptyRegion[2] :> {\[Infinity], ArcTan @@ Subtract @@ #1}}
      ] &,
    Subsets[lines, {2}],
    {1}
    ];
  phis = Select[
    Cases[intersections, {_?(# > Norm[dims] &), phi_} :> 
      Mod[phi, Pi]], (Pi/3 < # < 2 Pi/3) &];
  If[
   phis == {},
   img,
   ImageRotate[img, Pi/2 - Median[phis], "MaxAreaCropping"]
   ]
  ]
```

`VerticalAlignment[image]` gives for the upper example:

[image]

Now I can do the following (mentioned in the beginning):

```
ListLinePlot[data[[All, 58, 1]], ImageSize -> Medium]
```

[image]

and determine the peak positions and their distances.

Comment: Strongly related if not a duplicate: "[Best method to find variation in width along the image of a slit?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/86396/280)"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using `Radon` instead of `ImageLines@EdgeDetect@`. No need for thinning the lines.

```
i     = ImageAdjust@Import@"https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRCH5.png";
cc    = ComponentMeasurements[MaxDetect[r = Radon@i, .1], "Centroid"];
angle = -cc[[All, 2, 1]] Pi/First@ImageDimensions@r// Mean;
ImageAdjust@ImageRotate[i, angle, Background -> Black]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The `0.1` in `MaxDetect[r = Radon@i, .1]` is empirical, but I found it working very well when using `Radon[ ]`. Otherwise you may find `FindThreshold[ ]` useful for estimating an ad hoc value.

Showing the alignment:

```
horline[i_Image, row_] := Graphics[{Orange, Thick, 
                              Line[{{0, row}, {Last@ImageDimensions@i, row}}]}]
With[{j = ImageAdjust@ImageRotate[i, angle, Background -> Black]}, 
                      Show[j, horline[j, #] & /@ cc[[All, 2, 2]]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: is there somewhere a good explanation about `MaxDetect` ?. I don't understand the documentation.

Comment: @andre Play with this `Print[ListPlot[t = Table[Sin[3 x] + 1, {x, 0, 2 Pi, .01}]]];
Manipulate[
 ListPlot[{t, MaxDetect[t, x]}, AxesOrigin -> {0, -1}], {x, 0, 2}]` I believe it should be clear

Comment: @andre You may use `cc = ComponentMeasurements[
   MaxDetect[r = #, FindThreshold@#] &@Radon@i, "Centroid"];` if you don't like my heuristics

Comment: I vote for your solution since you answered everything what I asked and in  addition measured the spacing ... thanks

Comment: @Dr. belisarius It's clear. Thanks !

Comment: I post a solution in the following just now for more common case to hats off to you. And if you are available help me to improve [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/108910/what-case-need-to-use-randon-transform),Please.

Comment: @Dr. belisarius, I will suggest two changes for strictly precise computation of positioning _orange_ lines on final image:
`angle=\[Pi]/2-(cc[[All,2,1]]/First@ImageDimensions@r-1/2)\[Pi]//Mean;`
and necessary:
`With[{j=ImageAdjust@ImageRotate[i,angle,Background->Black]},Show[j,horline[j,#]&/@(cc[[All,2,2]]-(Last@ImageDimensions@r-Last@ImageDimensions@j)/2)]]`
The result then [is](http://i.imgur.com/StpWCcU.jpg)

Answer (score 6):

I don't know about the generality of this method, but you seem to already have a general method.  This works on the image you provided, and is adapted from the code you posted,

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRCH5.png"];
ImageRotate[img, -ArcTan @@ 
   Flatten@(Differences /@ 
      Transpose[
       First@ImageLines[EdgeDetect@img, 
         MaxFeatures -> 1]]), "MaxAreaCropping"]
```

[image]

Essentially you just need to find one line using `ImageLines` and then find the angle it makes with the horizontal, then rotate it through the reverse of that angle.

Comment: Wau ... this is impressing ... thanks

Answer (score 4):

Another maybe interesting method strike on me with `PrincipalComponents`:

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRCH5.png"];
inipos = Position[
   ImageData@
    Image@First@Values@ComponentMeasurements[Binarize[img], "Mask"], 
   1., {2}];
mat = FindGeometricTransform[PrincipalComponents[N@inipos], 
    inipos][[2]];
ImageRotate@ImageTransformation[img, mat, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: @Dr. belisarius How about this?

Comment: Nice :). Also `ImageForwardTransformation[#, 
   Last@FindGeometricTransform[PrincipalComponents[#], #, 
       Transformation -> "Rigid"] &@
    N@Position[ImageData@MaxDetect[#, .1], 1, {2}], 
   PlotRange -> All] &@img`

Comment: BTW you can't ping another user like this. S/he ought to be participating in the comments thread below the current answer/question. I saw it while browsing

Answer (score 3):

Another method would be to minimize the height of the rotated and cropped image,

```
imgheight[a_?NumericQ] := 
 Last@ImageDimensions@ImageCrop@ImageRotate[Binarize@img, a]
NMinimize[{imgheight[a], -π <= a <= π}, a]
(* {92., {a -> -2.78909}} *)
```

The result,

```
ImageRotate[img, a /. %[[2]], "MaxAreaCropping"]
```

[image]

Comment: Also this method is very interesting ...

Answer (score 2):

So,I'm like the @Dr. belisarius's method with a mysterious `Radon`.But this solution will solve a more common case.When you original image is nearst vertical.`straightimage` will rotate it to vertical.If the origional image is nearst horizontal.It will do same thing.

```
img = ImageAdjust@Import@"https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRCH5.png";
imgrote = 
 ImageRotate[img, #, "SameRatioCropping"] & /@ Range[0, 3, 0.5]
```

[image]

```
straightimage[img_] := 
 Module[{lines = 
    ImageLines@
     DeleteSmallComponents[
      EdgeDetect[img, Method -> {"Canny", "StraightEdges" -> 0.4}]], 
   list},
  ImageRotate[img, 
   Mean@Select[
     list = Mod[-#, Pi/2, -Pi/4] & /@ ArcTan @@@ Subtract @@@ lines, 
     Chop[First@Commonest@Round[list, 1/1000] - #, 1/1000] === 0 &], 
   Background -> Transparent]]
```

**Example:**

```
straightimage /@ imgrote
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you .. this is very interesting