# Is there any way to speed up this image manipulator?

Tags: image-processing

This post is only a part of a broader analysis that I am performing on the image processing speed, but I think it's interesting in itself. I will post more in the next days. Now the problem is: I have a lot of images like this one

[image]

and I want straighten each of them. Obiously the rotation angle is not the same for all picture. To choose the correct one I have tried this:

```
numberFormat[arg_] := NumberForm[arg, {3, 3}, NumberSigns -> {"+", "-"}];
file = "c:\\degiorgi\\002\\z001.bmp";
img = Import[file, "BMP"];
Manipulate[
 ImageRotate[img, -t],
  Control[{{t, 0, Dynamic[numberFormat[t]]}, 0, 1, .1, 
  ControlType -> Slider}]
 ]
```

[image]

It works fine on little test images but grows deadly slow as image size increases and even to move the slider become practically impossibile. The same holds for

```
file = "c:\\degiorgi\\002\\z001.bmp";
img = Import[file, "BMP"];
r = Table[a, {a, 0, .5, .001}];
Manipulate[
 ImageRotate[img, -t]
 , Control[{t, r, ControlType -> PopupMenu}]
 ]
```

[image]

What am I doing wrong ? I think that all this is not affected by the machine performance because other image processing software, and vector drawing also, run fast.

In this specific case a possible workaround could be to process only the upper part of the image, but the main problem endures.

Comment: Look [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/108648/21532)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you are rotating the full resolution `Image` at every "step".
You can manipulate a thumbnail and apply the transformation to the full image afterwards.

```
numberFormat[arg_] :=  NumberForm[arg, {3, 3}, NumberSigns -> {"+", "-"}];

(* Get the full image *)
file = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYS4s.jpg";
img = Import[file];

(* Resize to 250 pixels*)
tmb = Thumbnail[img, 250];

 Manipulate[
  Column[
   {ImageRotate[tmb,-t], 
    Button["Save",Print[ImageRotate[img,-t]]]}
  ],
  Control[{{t,0,Dynamic[numberFormat[t]]},0,1,.1,ControlType->Slider}]
 ]
```

[image: Manipulate result]

Comment: Your hint fully solves my problem, thanks ! When are involved colorful images may be useful to compose Binarize and Thumbnail. I'm going to try.