# Remove the white margins of a Graphics3D figure

Tags: graphics3d

If the option `Boxed` is set to be `False` in `Graphics3D`, additional white margins may appear as shown in the following figure. Is it possible to remove the useless margins such that the borders touch the *contents*?

```
smallarray = 
 With[{L0 = 300, r0 = 50, unitcellsize = 400, origin = {0, 0, 0}, 
   la = 800, ra = 50 },
  Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[None], Yellow, 
    Table[{Cylinder[{{ix*unitcellsize, iy*unitcellsize - L0/2, 
         0}, {ix*unitcellsize, iy*unitcellsize + L0/2, 0}}, r0]}, {ix,
       1, 5}, {iy, 1, 5}], Arrowheads[0.1], Red, 
    Arrow[Tube[{origin, origin + {la, 0, 0}}, ra]], Magenta, 
    Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, origin + {0, la, 0}}, ra]], Cyan, 
    Arrow[Tube[{origin, origin + {0, 0, la}}, ra]]}, Boxed -> False, 
   Lighting -> Automatic, ViewPoint -> {Pi, Pi/2, Pi}, 
   ImageSize -> {Automatic, 400}]]
```

[image]

Comment: You can check out [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5568/cropping-a-plot-via-a-command) by @Jens to a question of mine several months ago for cropping 3D graphics.

Comment: Borderline duplicate: [Export Graphics without white edges](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1224/131)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The option you need is `Method->{"ShrinkWrap"->True}`. From the Documentation Center [Graphics3D>Options>Method](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Graphics3D.html):

> By default, empty space may appear around a graphical image ..
>      Use `Method->{"ShrinkWrap"->True}` to prevent the inclusion of empty space.

```
smallarray = 
 With[{L0 = 300, r0 = 50, unitcellsize = 400, origin = {0, 0, 0},  la = 800, ra = 50}, 
 Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[None], Yellow, 
 Table[{Cylinder[{{ix*unitcellsize, iy*unitcellsize - L0/2, 
     0}, {ix*unitcellsize, iy*unitcellsize + L0/2, 0}}, r0]},
  {ix,  1, 5}, {iy, 1, 5}], Arrowheads[0.1], Red, 
 Arrow[Tube[{origin, origin + {la, 0, 0}}, ra]], Magenta, 
 Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, origin + {0, la, 0}}, ra]], Cyan, 
 Arrow[Tube[{origin, origin + {0, 0, la}}, ra]]}, Boxed -> False, 
 Lighting -> Automatic, ViewPoint -> {Pi, Pi/2, Pi}, 
 ImageSize -> {Automatic, 400}, PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
 ImagePadding -> 0, Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> True}]]
```

[image] [image]

Comment: I'm glad to see that has been added to the documentation. +1

Comment: By the way, I see that your avatar is changing with your IP address again.  Why did you remove the email from your profile?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, just added my e-mail to my profile (was confused about public visibility of the e-mail address in the profile:)

Comment: @kguler The email and real name fields are not publicly visible. You can check what is visible publicly by viewing your profile using an incognito session in Chrome (or its equivalent in FF/Safari/Opera/IE)

Comment: If I add some text into the figure such as `Table[Text[Style[ix, 24, Bold], {ix*unitcellsize, 0, 0}], {ix, 1, 5}]` and use  `Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> True}`, the number **5**  won't appear. What happened in this case?

Comment: @kglr:  You *MUST* work for WRI... you simply know too damn much!   So very helpful. (+1)