# Unwanted chopping of a figure while combining a plot with a graph

Tags: plotting, graphics

I have tried to combine a graph with two plots, but some parts of figure are missing after the combination. I have tried to fix it by changing the image size, but it did not work (by the way, since it is going to appear in a journal, if the size is small, it's resolution won't be enough for publication, especially for jepg files).

The graphics code is here:

```
g1 = Graphics3D[
{Green, Arrowheads[0.05], 
Arrow[Tube[{{-6, 2.9, .5}, {-4, 2.9, .5}}, 0.1]]}, Boxed -> False,
ImageSize -> 1500];

g2 = Graphics3D[
{Green, Arrowheads[0.07], 
Arrow[Tube[{{4, 2.9, .5}, {8, 2.9, .5}}, 0.15]]}, Boxed -> False, 
ImageSize -> 1500];

g3 = Graphics3D[
{Red, Arrowheads[0.05], 
Arrow[Tube[{{-6, 4.1, .5}, {-4, 4.1, .5}}, 0.1]]}, Boxed -> False,
ImageSize -> 1500];

g4 = Graphics3D[
{Red, Arrowheads[0.07], 
Arrow[Tube[{{4, 4.1, .5}, {8, 4.1, .5}}, 0.15]]}, Boxed -> False, 
ImageSize -> 1500];

g5 = Graphics3D[
{{EdgeForm[{Thickness[.000001], GrayLevel@0}], RGBColor[0, 0, 1], 
 Cuboid[{-4, 0, 0}, {4, 2.4, 1}], 
 Text[Style["|z\[RightAngleBracket]", 20, Black, Bold], {-8, 1, 
   2}]},
{EdgeForm[{Thickness[.000001], GrayLevel@0}], Blue, 
 Cuboid[{-4, 3.4, 0}, {4, 3.6, 1}]},
{EdgeForm[{Thickness[.000001], GrayLevel@0}], Blue, 
 Cuboid[{-4, 4.6, 0}, {4, 7, 1}]},
{EdgeForm[{Thickness[.000001], GrayLevel@0}], Blue, 
 Cuboid[{-4, 0, 0}, {4, 7, -1}]},
{Cyan, Opacity[.95], Cuboid[{-4, 2.4, 0}, {4, 3.4, 1}], 
 Text[Style["\[Gamma]", 20, Black, Bold], {0, 3.1, 1}]},
{Yellow, Opacity[.95], Cuboid[{-4, 3.6, 0}, {4, 4.6, 1}], 
 Text[Style["g(t)", 20, Black, Bold], {0, 4.2, 1}]}},
Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> 1500];

f1 = Show[{g1, g2, g3, g4, g5}, ViewPoint -> {-1, -1, .7}]
```

As an example, suppose we want to add sine and cosine plots to the graph. So,

```
f2 = GraphicsRow[{Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 7}, GridLines -> None, 
PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.015], Blue}, 
FrameLabel -> {Style["x", FontSlant -> Italic], "Sin(x)"}, 
FrameTicksStyle -> {Directive[Black, 12], Directive[Black, 12]}, 
LabelStyle -> {Bold, Directive[Black, 16]}, Frame -> True, 
PlotRange -> All, 
Epilog -> {Text[Style["(a)", Bold, 12], {.5, .8}]}],

Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 7}, GridLines -> None, 
PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.015], Blue}, 
FrameLabel -> {Style["x", FontSlant -> Italic], "Cos(x)"}, 
FrameTicksStyle -> {Directive[Black, 12], Directive[Black, 12]}, 
LabelStyle -> {Bold, Directive[Black, 16]}, Frame -> True, 
PlotRange -> All, 
Epilog -> {Text[Style["(b)", Bold, 12], {.5, .8}]}]}]
```

Since I didn't want the white margin of the final figure, I tried the following code (I used this link: [Remove the white margins of a Graphics3D figure](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21031/remove-the-white-margins-of-a-graphics3d-figure)):

```
GraphicsColumn[{f1, f2}, Spacings -> -180, 
Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> True}]
```

The result is here:

[image]

So, how can I avoid chopping the figure while the resolution is acceptable (I tried bigger image sizes, but in that case no part of the plot appeared!

Comment: try adding the option `Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> True}` to `Show` that produces `f1` (not to `GraphicsColumn`)

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but the final image has still the white margins. If I add Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> True} to the plots and the graph, some part of the plot is missing.