# How to remove white margins of a rendered image of an Image3D object?

Tags: image3d

This question is related to [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21031/remove-the-white-margins-of-a-graphics3d-figure). In the case of `Graphics3D`, there is an option for `Method->{"ShrinkWrap"->True}`, however, there is no such option for `Image3D`.

Consider an example as

```
head = ExampleData[{"TestImage3D", "CThead"}];
```

and a sample rendering as

```
Image3D[head, 
 ColorFunction -> (Blend[{{0., 
   RGBColor[0.05635, 0.081, 0.07687, 0.]}, {0.277199, 
   RGBColor[0.987197, 0.564838, 0., 0.]}, {0.488426, 
   RGBColor[1., 0.793177, 0.257829, 1.]}, {0.583912, 
   RGBColor[1., 0.889247, 0.388486, 0.]}, {1., 
   RGBColor[1., 0.6436, 0.03622, 0.]}}, #1] & )]
```

I tried using the `Method->{"ShrinkWrap"->True}` option. But it does not work. How can I remove the white margins as it can be done for `Graphics3D`?

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like this?

```
Show[
 Image3D[head, 
  ColorFunction -> (Blend[{{0., 
        RGBColor[0.05635, 0.081, 0.07687, 0.]}, {0.277199, 
        RGBColor[0.987197, 0.564838, 0., 0.]}, {0.488426, 
        RGBColor[1., 0.793177, 0.257829, 1.]}, {0.583912, 
        RGBColor[1., 0.889247, 0.388486, 0.]}, {1., 
        RGBColor[1., 0.6436, 0.03622, 0.]}}, #1] &), 
  ViewPoint -> {0, 0, Infinity}],
 Boxed -> False, PlotRangePadding -> None, 
 Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> True}]
```