# How to reduce the spaces in the edges of the exported plot as optimal?

Tags: plotting, export

```
p1 = ComplexPlot3D[(z^2 + 1)/(z^2 - 1), {z, -2 - 2 I, 2 + 2 I}, 
  PlotTheme -> "Detailed"]
Export["plot.png", p1]
```

When I export the plot, I have redundat spaces. How to reduce the spaces as optimal?
[image]

Comment: Right click and using `Trim Bounding Box `

Comment: Thanks. What is the code for `Trim Bounding Box` instead of right click? Because I will export the figure via command `Export`

Comment: better to export to pdf and not png,  as quality is better. You can import pdf as graphics to Latex. And For web browsing, you can always convert pdf images to svg using free tools, which is better than png.

Comment: In fact, I want to export it .as .eps or pdf for LaTeX. But Mathematica doesn't give good results in 3D plots to get vector format (such as .eps or .pdf) while 2D plots are good. (Or I can' t achieve)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried borrowing a technique from [21031](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21031/remove-the-white-margins-of-a-graphics3d-figure):

```
p2 = ComplexPlot3D[(z^2 + 1)/(z^2 - 1), {z, -2 - 2 I, 2 + 2 I}, 
  PlotTheme -> "Detailed", Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> True}]
```

but that didn't change much.

Then I tried:

```
p3 = ImageCrop[Rasterize[p2, ImageResolution -> 300]]
Export["C:/plot3.png", p3]
```

which looks ok.

[image]

---

**Without Rasterizing**

Using `SphericalRegion->False`:

```
p4 = ComplexPlot3D[(z^2 + 1)/(z^2 - 1), {z, -2 - 2 I, 2 + 2 I}, 
  PlotTheme -> "Detailed", SphericalRegion -> False]

Export["C:/plot.png", p4]
```

Comment: All right, is there a way without rasterizing the picture?

Comment: I have updated the answer after trying many options. Hopefully this works for you.

Comment: In my case, `Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> True}` combined with `ImagePadding -> None` works well.