# PNG image is exported smaller size than imported

Tags: export, image-processing

I upload a PNG file and then split it into its red, green and blue components. I then save these components.

The original image is 1440 x 764 pixels, 2.21MB. But the 3 saved files are each 360x198 pixels, 96.9 KB.

Why is the output image so much smaller? Here's my code:

```
    file = "C:\\myFile.png";
    stem = "C:\\";
    img = Import[file];
    imgData = ImageData[img];
    rgbData = 
      Table[ArrayPlot[imgData[[;; , ;; , n]], 
        ColorFunction -> (GrayLevel[#] & 1)], {n, 1, 3}];
    Table[Export [FileNameJoin[{stem, ToString[n] <> ".png"}], 
       rgbData[[n]], "PNG"], {n, 1, 3}];
```

Comment: you should use ColorSeparate to separate colorchannels

Comment: Try using `Image` rather than `ArrayPlot` : http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/24124/2079

Comment: @george2079: Yes that worked! Basically, I used `Image` instead of `ArrayPlot` and changed `ColorFunction->(blah)` to `ColorSpace->"Grayscale"` and I got the result I was looking for. But your comment is too short to accept as an answer. Could you expand a bit? Also -- why does `ArrayPlot` reduce the image size? That doesn't make any sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ArrayPlot` is not designed for 1:1 mapping of array values to pixels, in fact in typical usage (small array) `ArrayPlot` generates a raster that is much larger than the input array dimensions.

You may get  what you want using the `PixelConstrained` option:

```
 ArrayPlot[ data , PixelConstrained -> 1,  Frame -> False]
 ImageDimensions@%  ==  Reverse@Dimensions[data]
```

> True

Using `Image` ( https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/24124/2079 ) Is a more direct/reliable approach however.