# Method Shrinkwrap Messes up editting Graphics

Tags: graphics, image, version-8, windows

If you try resizing or moving the `Inset` in the following interface, the `Graphics` becomes [incredibly jerky](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYDT1.png) and borderline unusable.

```
Graphics[{LightGray, Disk[],
  Inset[
   Graphics[{Rectangle[]}, ImageSize -> 200, 
    Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> True}]]
  }]
```

Now if I remove `Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> True}` the interface (`Drawing Tools`) works fine but a border is added around the `Graphic`

```
Graphics[{LightGray, Disk[],
  Inset[
    Graphics[{Rectangle[]},
      ImageSize -> 200]]
  }]
```

Is there a way to Shrinkwrap or effectively [remove the border](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1224/export-graphics-without-white-edges/1227#1227) without destroying the ability to edit `Graphics`?  As an alternative, might there be a way to embed the `Inset` data directly into the `Graphics`.  Currently it only serves the purpose of adding an `ImageSize` value to the `Inset` Graphics.

Comment: A small possible temporary solution is to add `Rasterize@Graphics` in place of `Graphics`.  It isn't really a permanent solution but the editor does work without glitching out.

Comment: On OSX I don't get the messed up graphics with `"ShrinkWrap" -> True`. Can you please specify you exact system and *Mathematica* version? This might be important.

Comment: @halirutan V8.0.1 and Windows 7

Comment: Confirmed problem with v9 on Windows 7. Using `ImagePadding -> 0, PlotRangePadding -> 0` instead of the method option seems to be a workaround.

Comment: @SimonWoods After reading 500's comment [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1224#comments-1226) it appears he is right that ImagePadding and PlotRangePadding due clip the padding, but honestly it probably varies between systems.  Is is like a 1px or 2px difference.  Example http://pastebin.com/BayM6hx7