# How to prevent ShrinkWrap from removing text?

Tags: graphics, bugs

**Bug persisting through 11.2.0**

---

When I use `ShrinkWrap` to remove the white space around my 3D graphics, it always removes any text around the edges. Say for example I plot a sphere and some text:

```
Show[Graphics3D[{Sphere[], Text[Style["ABC", 24], {1, 1, 1}]}], Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

And if I use `ShrinkWrap`, it removed the text and part of the sphere

```
Show[Graphics3D[{Sphere[], Text[Style["ABC", 24], {1, 1, 1}]}], Boxed -> False,
 Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> True}]
```

[image]

How to prevent this?

Comment: This is a bug. Please report it to the support. BTW, with version 8.0.4 the ball isn't cropped: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1amup.png).

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov OK, where do I report this bug?

Comment: You send email to support@wolfram.com with MWE and information about your OS, version number, etc... you'l' get back a CASE number.

Comment: Nasser already answered about support. They'll ask you for output of `{$Version, $ReleaseNumber, $LicenseID}`, so I recommend to include this in the original report.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this to see if it works for you.

```
Show[Graphics3D[{Sphere[],Text[Style["ABC",24],{1,1,1}]}],
  Boxed->False,
  Method->{"ShrinkWrap"->True},
  ViewVector->{{9,2,2},{0,0,0}}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Update

Using `ImagePadding -> 0, PlotRangePadding -> 0` helps a little, as given by comment by Simon woods in [method-shrinkwrap-messes-up-editting-graphics](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30526/method-shrinkwrap-messes-up-editting-graphics) But the text is still missing, but sphere is not cropped.

```
Show[Graphics3D[{Sphere[],Text[Style["ABC",24],{1,1,1}]}],
Boxed->False,Method->{"ShrinkWrap"->True},
ImagePadding->0,PlotRangePadding->0]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: (+1) Can you explain why specifying `ViewVector` helps in this case?

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov  I just noticed that by moving the image with the mouse  did bring the text back. So by trial and error, this view vector was the best to show the text in this case.

Comment: How do I know which specification for `ViewVector` to use though? Can it be done when there are multiple texts at several different margins?

Comment: @L.Quen as I said, this was by trial and error for this case. This is just a workaround for the example you showed. This looks like a bug as was suggested. I could not find a general workaround for all cases at this time. The text is there. (you can see that by moving the image with the mouse). It is just that the view gets messed up and needs manual adjustment.

Comment: OK thanks for the help