# Remove the white space bounding a 3D plot

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d

The following simple 3D plot always bears a rather wide empty space surrounding the sphere. I only need the sphere and vectors without box or axes. How to remove/control the empty space?

A few padding options I tried do not seem to help. And nonzero `PlotRangePadding` seems necessary to have a few vectors not cut at the boundary.

```
m = 1.1;
SliceVectorPlot3D[{y, -x, z}, 
 x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 1, {x, -m, m}, {y, -m, m}, {z, -m, m}, 
 VectorPoints -> 5, VectorSizes -> 0.9, ViewPoint -> {0.1, -2, 2}, 
 ViewVertical -> {-1, 0., 0.}, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, 
 PlotRangePadding -> Automatic, ImagePadding -> 0, ImageMargins -> 0, 
 ImageSize -> Medium]
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default `PlotRange` setting for [`SliceVectorPlot3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SliceVectorPlot3D.html) is `{Full, Full, Full}` (see the *Details and Options* section). This means that the full regions of space corresponding to the specified variable ranges will be shown, *including any portions in which your function has no plot*. The latter will show up as empty space.

To restrict the plot to the minimum calculated range that just includes the function's plot, you want `PlotRange -> All` instead. Add that option (and perhaps remove all the other padding, margins etc) to minimize white space:

```
m = 1.1;
SliceVectorPlot3D[
  {y, -x, z}, x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 1,
  {x, -m, m}, {y, -m, m}, {z, -m, m}, 
  PlotRange -> All,
  Axes -> False, Boxed -> False
  VectorPoints -> 5, VectorSizes -> 0.9
]
```

[image: minimal size plot]

---

To explain the difference between `Full` and `All` in the context of `PlotRange`, I find these two examples pretty clear:

```
Plot[Sqrt[x], {x, -3, 3}, PlotRange -> #]& /@ {Full, All}
```

[image: left: plot with large white space for x<0. Right: plot range has been automatically restricted to x>0]

In the plot on the left, the entire $-3<x<3$ range is shown even though nothing can be plotted in the negative $x$ region because the function is complex-valued there. In the plot in the right, the plot range is restricted to only include the values of x for which a plot is generated (i.e. $x\geq 0$.

Comment: Saved my day. Thank you!

Comment: @xiaohuamao Glad it helped! Thank you for the accept as well.

Answer (score 4):

Another possibility is to use `Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> True}` (previously featured e.g. [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1224)):

```
With[{m = 1.1},
     SliceVectorPlot3D[{y, -x, z}, x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 1,
                       {x, -m, m}, {y, -m, m}, {z, -m, m}, 
                       VectorPoints -> 5, VectorSizes -> 0.9, ViewPoint -> {0.1, -2, 2}, 
                       ViewVertical -> {-1, 0., 0.}, Boxed -> False, Axes -> None, 
                       PlotRangePadding -> Automatic, ImageSize -> Medium, 
                       Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> True}]]
```

[image: shrink-wrapped plot]

Comment: Interesting! Never heard of it.